# Associative array without toString, etc

Tags: javascript, object, maps, associative-array

I want to create an associative array:

```
var aa = {} // Equivalent to Object(), new Object(), etc...
```

And I want to be sure that any key I access is going to be a number:

```
aa['hey'] = 4.3;
aa['btar'] = 43.1;
```

I know JavaScript doesn't have typing, so I can't automatically check this, but I can ensure in my own code that I only assign strings to this `aa`.

Now I'm taking keys from the user. I want to display the value for that key. However, if the user gives me something like "toString", the user gets back a function, not an int! Is there a way to make sure any string the user gives me is only something I define?

Is the only solution something like the following?

```
delete aa['toString'];
delete aa['hasOwnProperty'];
```

etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
function getValue(id){
  return (!isNaN(aa[id])) ? aa[id] : undefined;
}
```

Alternatively, I recommend this generic solution:

```
function getValue(hash,key) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(hash,key) ? hash[key] : undefined;
}
```

Note the following: The key will internally be converted to a string because the key is actually a name of an attribute.

```
var test = {
  2: "Defined as numeric",
  "2": "Defined as string"
}

alert(test[2]); // Alerts "Defined as string"
```

If trying to use an object:

```
var test = {}, test2 = {};
test[test2] = "message"; // Using an object as a key.

alert(test[test2]); // Alerts "message". It looks like it works...

alert(test[test2.toString()]);
// If it really was an object this would not have worked,
// but it also alerts "message".
```

Now that you know that it is always a string, let’s use it:

```
var test = {};

var test2 = {
    toString:function(){return "some_unique_value";}
    // Note that the attribute name (toString) don't need quotes.
}

test[test2] = "message";
alert(test["some_unique_value"]); // Alerts "message".
```

Comment: yup, the 2nd would work - thanks! the first will not at all, i don't think =P.

Comment: It has to be Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(hash, key)

The call method of any function object allows us to call the hasOwnProperty method as if it were a method of the hash object

Comment: @Claudio: The first one (with isNaN) works because a function or undefined is not a number. So by testing if aa[id] is a number, you get that number, or else you get undefined. I have tested it in firefox and it works there.

Comment: @Claudio: And you said you wanted a number, right? ;) But the second one is more generic and works for all types of values. Just remember that internally the key is a string.

Comment: @some: ah, thanks, i didn't catch that. my use case was actually more general. the key is a string? isn't it a hashed version of whatever you pass in? or is it the hashed version of the string. if it is, then how does it work for objs you define yourself?

Comment: @Claudio: No, its not hashed. The "key" is the name of the attribute in the object, and therefore must be a string (internally .toString() of the key will be called so you can use a numeric, but it will silently be converted to a string )

Comment: @some: very interesting about the hash, very valuable information! thanks. wish i could double-upvote you.

Comment: @Claudiu: Too bad I put this as community wiki then ;) (and sorry for misspelling your name)

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use hasOwnProperty to check that the key is something you explicitly added to the array. So instead of:

```
function findNumber(userEnteredKey) {
    return aa[userEnteredKey];
}
```

you'd say:

```
function findNumber(userEnteredKey) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(aa, userEnteredKey))
        return aa[userEnteredKey];
}
```

Alternately, you could use typeof to check that anything is a number before returning it. But I like the hasOwnProperty approach, because it'll keep you from returning anything that you didn't intentionally put in the array.

Comment: Problem with this is that it will fail if the user has entered the key "hasOwnProperty".

Comment: You'd use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(aa, userEnteredKey)`

Comment: @Moss: +1 for hasOwnProperty.

Comment: Ooh, that's what I get for being out of practice with JavaScript. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new key, prepend it with some string constant of your own:

```
var a = {};
var k = 'MYAPP.COLLECTIONFOO.KEY.';

function setkey(userstring)
{
  a[k + userstring] = 42;
}

function getkey(userstring)
{
  return a[k + userstring];
}
```