# JavaScript hashmap equivalent

Tags: javascript, data-structures, language-features, hashmap

As made clear in update 3 on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367440/javascript-associative-array-without-tostring-etc#367454), this notation:

```
var hash = {};
hash[X]
```

does not actually hash the object `X`; it actually just converts `X` to a string (via `.toString()` if it's an object, or some other built-in conversions for various primitive types) and then looks that string up, without hashing it, in "`hash`". Object equality is also not checked - if two different objects have the same string conversion, they will just overwrite each other.

Given this - are there any efficient implementations of hashmaps in JavaScript?

(For example, the second Google result of [`javascript hashmap`](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS299US303&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript%20hashmap) yields an implementation which is O(n) for any operation. Various other results ignore the fact that different objects with equivalent string representations overwrite each other.

Comment: @Claudiu: Sorry for the edit, but the "Map" in the title was really misleading. Roll back if you disagree, I did not intend to patronize. :)

Comment: @Claudiu: You ask a lot of questions about javascript. Good questions. I like that.

Comment: @Claudiu: Also, could you link to the Google result you refer to? Different local versions of Google return different results, the implementation you refer to does not even seem to show up for me.

Comment: @Tomalak: I was just going to write exactly the same thing!

Comment: ty all. i've added the google search. @some: yep, I've just started studying this language. it's interesting!

Comment: @Claudiu No, don't link to google. Link to the page you were talking about (which you happened to find through google). Linking to google has all the same problems as explaining what to search for: google customizing results based on location or on search history, google's results changing over time (currently, this is the top result for that search) and anything else that can make it show different results.

Answer (score 430, accepted):

Hash your objects yourself manually, and use the resulting strings as keys for a regular JavaScript dictionary. After all, you are in the best position to know what makes your objects unique. That's what I do.

Example:

```
var key = function(obj){
  // Some unique object-dependent key
  return obj.totallyUniqueEmployeeIdKey; // Just an example
};

var dict = {};

dict[key(obj1)] = obj1;
dict[key(obj2)] = obj2;
```

This way you can control indexing done by JavaScript without heavy lifting of memory allocation, and overflow handling.

Of course, if you truly want the "industrial-grade solution", you can build a class parameterized by the key function, and with all the necessary API of the container, but … we use JavaScript, and trying to be simple and lightweight, so this functional solution is simple and fast.

The key function can be as simple as selecting right attributes of the object, e.g., a key, or a set of keys, which are already unique, a combination of keys, which are unique together, or as complex as using some cryptographic hashes like in [DojoX encoding](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/encoding/), or [DojoX UUID](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/uuid/). While the latter solutions may produce unique keys, personally I try to avoid them at all costs, especially, if I know what makes my objects unique.

**Update in 2014:** Answered back in 2008 this simple solution still requires more explanations. Let me clarify the idea in a Q&A form.

*Your solution doesn't have a real hash. Where is it???*

JavaScript is a high-level language. Its basic primitive ([Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Objects)) includes a hash table to keep properties. This hash table is usually written in a low-level language for efficiency. Using a simple object with string keys we use an efficiently implemented hash table without any efforts on our part.

*How do you know they use a hash?*

There are three major ways to keep a collection of objects addressable by a key:

- Unordered. In this case to retrieve an object by its key we have to go over all keys stopping when we find it. On average it will take n/2 comparisons.
- Ordered.

  - Example #1: a sorted array — doing a binary search we will find our key after ~log2(n) comparisons on average. Much better.
  - Example #2: a tree. Again it'll be ~log(n) attempts.
- Hash table. On average, it requires a constant time. Compare: O(n) vs. O(log n) vs. O(1). Boom.

Obviously JavaScript objects use hash tables in some form to handle general cases.

*Do browser vendors really use hash tables???*

Really.

- Chrome/node.js/[V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/):
  [JSObject](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.h#L1680). Look for
  [NameDictionary](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.h#L3618) and
  [NameDictionaryShape](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.h#L3606) with
  pertinent details in [objects.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.cc)
  and [objects-inl.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects-inl.h).
- Firefox/[Gecko](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev):
  [JSObject](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/jsobj.h#L99),
  [NativeObject](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/vm/NativeObject.h#L349), and
  [PlainObject](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/vm/NativeObject.h#L1238) with pertinent details in
  [jsobj.cpp](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/jsobj.cpp) and
  [vm/NativeObject.cpp](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/vm/NativeObject.cpp).

*Do they handle collisions?*

Yes. See above. If you found a collision on unequal strings, please do not hesitate to file a bug with a vendor.

*So what is your idea?*

If you want to hash an object, find what makes it unique and use it as a key. Do not try to calculate a real hash or emulate hash tables — it is already efficiently handled by the underlying JavaScript object.

Use this key with JavaScript's `Object` to leverage its built-in hash table while steering clear of possible clashes with default properties.

Examples to get you started:

- If your objects include a unique user name — use it as a key.
- If it includes a unique customer number — use it as a key.

  - If it includes unique government-issued numbers like US [SSNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number), or a passport number, and your system doesn't allow duplicates — use it as a key.
- If a combination of fields is unique — use it as a key.

  - US state abbreviation + driver license number makes an excellent key.
  - Country abbreviation + passport number is an excellent key too.
- Some function on fields, or a whole object, can return a unique value — use it as a key.

*I used your suggestion and cached all objects using a user name. But some wise guy is named "toString", which is a built-in property! What should I do now?*

Obviously, if it is even remotely possible that the resulting key will exclusively consists of Latin characters, you should do something about it. For example, add any non-Latin Unicode character you like at the beginning or at the end to un-clash with default properties: "#toString", "#MarySmith". If a composite key is used, separate key components using some kind of non-Latin delimiter: "name,city,state".

In general, this is the place where we have to be creative and select the easiest keys with given limitations (uniqueness, potential clashes with default properties).

Note: unique keys do not clash by definition, while potential hash clashes will be handled by the underlying `Object`.

*Why don't you like industrial solutions?*

IMHO, the best code is no code at all: it has no errors, requires no maintenance, easy to understand, and executes instantaneously. All "hash tables in JavaScript" I saw were >100 lines of code, and involved multiple objects. Compare it with: `dict[key] = value`.

Another point: is it even possible to beat a performance of a primordial object written in a low-level language, using JavaScript and the very same primordial objects to implement what is already implemented?

*I still want to hash my objects without any keys!*

We are in luck: [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) (released in June 2015) defines [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Judging by the definition, they can use an object's address as a key, which makes objects instantly distinct without artificial keys. OTOH, two different, yet identical objects, will be mapped as distinct.

Comparison breakdown from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared):

> Objects are similar to Maps in that both let you set keys to values,
> retrieve those values, delete keys, and detect whether something is
> stored at a key. Because of this (and because there were no built-in
> alternatives), Objects have been used as Maps historically; however,
> there are important differences that make using a Map preferable in
> certain cases:
>
> - The keys of an Object are Strings and Symbols, whereas they can be any value for a Map, including functions, objects, and any primitive.
> - The keys in Map are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus, when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of
>   insertion.
> - You can get the size of a Map easily with the size property, while the number of properties in an Object must be determined manually.
> - A Map is an iterable and can thus be directly iterated, whereas iterating over an Object requires obtaining its keys in some fashion
>   and iterating over them.
> - An Object has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map that could collide with your keys if you're not careful. As of ES5 this can
>   be bypassed by using map = Object.create(null), but this is seldom
>   done.
> - A Map may perform better in scenarios involving frequent addition and removal of key pairs.

Comment: The use of arbitrary strings as JavaScript object keys must be handled with care; were the `hash` function to return `__proto__` for example, your program would fail. See http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/objects-as-maps.html

Comment: This doesn't look like a proper map, because you don't handle collisions. If this happens to be true: hash(obj1) == hash(obj2), you is going to lose your data.

Comment: Heaven help you when both "PAUL AINLEY" and "PAULA INLEY" register in your system...

Comment: @MattR Actually your example will work properly without the heaven help even with a mock hash function. I hope that other readers will realize that an over-simplified non-realistic hash function was used as a placeholder to demonstrate a different technique. Both code comments, and the answer itself stress that it is not real. Selection of proper keys are discussed in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Regarding a real hash function returning `__proto__` as its result: I am not aware of proper hashes doing that, and if there are some, I advise against using such functions. But if somebody wants to be uber-sure that it doesn't happen, just prefix your hash with a non-alphabet symbol like so: `dict["|" + hash(o)] = o;` --- it will eliminate all possible clashes with internal names.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin Using cryptographic hashing isn't going to help you if the data you feed *into* the hash has any risk of collision. Either your data has a unique key or it doesn't, but your example of concatenating names is flawed for that purpose. (And, to be honest, it's not at all clear in your answer that you consider using the name as over-simplified or non-realistic).

Comment: @MattR Code comments like "some cool hashing" and "just an example" should give away that it is .... an example. The answer starts with "you are in the best position to know what makes your objects unique" --- I hope most of the readers have read it correctly. :-) The last paragraph is talking about uniqueness as well. I am not going to post it here --- I hope you can read all four paragraphs of the answer.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin -- yes, it was clear that your example was an example.  (Note that, "example" does not by any means imply "over-simplified" or "non-realistic".) However, it needs to be emphasised -- as your answer does not -- that your "hash" must be incapable of causing a collision on your data. Doubly so, because this is an unusual requirement for a hash function.

Comment: @MattR I hope I clarified all your misunderstandings. If not, let me know what is still unclear.

Comment: @MattR it looks like you are the only one misunderstanding the answer.  Just look above: Julien alerted about hash functions returning `__proto__` as its hash value, and beefeather warned about hash collisions. You started with a wrong data example, which actually works even with the simplistic "hash" example I gave (I wrote about reusing JS objects as maps, not about hash function theory), and it went all downhill for you from there. I am glad that now you don't have any misunderstandings.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin -- you are still mistaken, I'm afraid. Your example is still prone to hash collisions. Don't think that just putting the last name first will somehow help you!

Comment: This is just plain wrong and should not be the accepted answer. This map does not handle collisions and is not a hashmap.

Comment: @CallumRogers I added explanations to the answer addressing your concerns, and comments of others. Cheers!

Comment: If you're not supposed to compute an actual hash in that function, wouldn't it be more appropriately named `key` or something similar?

Comment: @jpmc26 good thinking, I updated the text to be less confusing. The reason I used the term "hash" at all was due to how the question was formulated, not because any other important reasons.

Comment: How does Javascript efficiently handle so many key-value pairs efficiently - given that many keys will be heavily scattered? Does it use large maps that store multiple objects to create more sparse maps? I'm assuming these maps are hash-based for efficient lookups which only worsens internal fragmentation.

Comment: @bluejamesbond All good questions. You are welcome to find answers in the code --- I gave initial links in the answer. I am sure that studying the code you will find a lot of interesting in the world of hash tables, overflow management, and so on.

Comment: This is plain wrong, hash collisions are not handled.

Comment: @Daniel Care to give an example, or, even better, a link to a filed bug report?

Comment: @Daniel Totally forgot --- what browser gave you a problem?

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin e,g. x is firstname="123", lastname="456",  y is firstname="12", lastname = "3456".

Comment: @Daniel were comments like "some unique object-dependent key" and later "just an example" all around that code not enough to underscore that it is a stupid example? What if your object doesn't have "firstName" and "lastName" --- will you still use it as is without thinking? What about more realistic suggestions later in the answer? (Just to be pedantic: your example will produce two distinct strings: "456123" and "345612"). OTOH, you are not the first person to fixate on a strawman code (and give a wrong counter-example). I'll edit the example later to make it more to your liking.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin Sorry, read too fast. Actually I read your old version like this:     
    dict[hash(obj1)] = obj1;     dict[hash(obj2)] = obj2; Hashings allow collisions and you have to deal with it, keys don't. After changing hash to key, now got it. Sorry again.

Comment: The question asks for an implementation that handles collisions, and this answer says ignore collisions because it's javascript.  That is utter nonsense.  The fact that `object` is internally implemented as a hash table is completely irrelevant, because it does not expose the important collision handling.  If you can generate a totally unique ID for any given element, then yes you can simply map the key inside of an `object` and everything will be peachy.  But, that doesn't make it a hash table.

Comment: @jconder In my answer collisions are not ignored at all, but handled internally by an underlying Object --- it is a practical solution for a practical problem. What exactly do you, personally you, want to see covered there? What API is missing for you?

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin Collisions in your solution are not handled internally: they are not handled at all.  If there is a collision in the hash then you lose data, period.  It's not that it is a bad approach for certain applications, but it's not a proper hash table.

Comment: @jconder Could you give an example I can try? Feel free to write to me directly.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin They've already been given in the comments.  If your hash function is hash(x) { return x.firstname + x.lastname; } then 'Sue smith' and 'Sues mith' will collide into the same spot, and the last one added will overwrite the first.  That is a collision - it's not handled.  As I said, it's not that I disagree with your approach but that it doesn't handle collisions.  It's not a hash table.

Comment: @jconder I specifically removed the issue of how to generate a key from the answer, which is an application-specific functionality. Just don't do anything dumb - see the answer for pointers. Obviously a key generating function (whatever you use) can handle collisions in any way you like, or use the standard `Map` for unique objects. The latter is mentioned in the answer too. If you favor multimaps, just keep arrays as dictionary items, so objects with the same key are kept together.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin could you please snub this entire history lesson and just talk about the now released ES6/Map? This is really entirely excessive.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin Most people doesn't read you have answer this BEFORE ES6 even appears... Let me congratulate for your deep JS knowledge.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin, So which hash function does the [built-in Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) use?

Comment: @Pacerier AFAIK it doesn't use any. Instead it uses a memory address of an object (unavailable directly in JavaScript) as a numeric key. The side-effect of this is when you create an identical object to the one included in a map/set, it will not be found, because it will have a different memory address, and map/set don't do deep comparison for efficiency. That's the difference: a hash function usually operates on content (so my example would work), while the bultin map/set operates on object identities. Incidentally this is why this answer is still relevant in the age of ES2015. :-)

Comment: usage example `var key = function(obj){
  // some unique object-dependent key
  return obj.id; // just an example
};

var dict = {};

dict[key({'id': 1 , 'count' : 0})] = {'id': 1 , 'count' : 0};
dict[key({'id': 2 , 'count' : 5})] = {'id': 2 , 'count' : 5};

console.log(dict[key({'id': 1})]);`

Comment: Chiming in here: http://ryanmorr.com/true-hash-maps-in-javascript/ Found this link as well as this SO question when doing my own research on how to implement a sane map solution. However, it looks like there is a native map solution now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Link broken: jsobj.cpp -> correct linkt is probably: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/vm/JSObject.cpp

Comment: Might be worth updating this answer now that `Set` and `Map` are standard JS features. A lot of the extra explanation is unnecessary and probably confusing to newer JS developers.

Comment: In comments you guess the JS `Map` just relies on identity. But in that case `myMap.set('peter'); myMap.get('peter')` wouldn't work, so I don't think that's true. Or does jS create a constant for every new string it meets?

Comment: Map/set can use primitive and object/function values as keys. It will use a primitive value as a hash base. For an object, it will be its address. Read more on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 176):

## Problem description

JavaScript has no built-in general *map* type (sometimes called *associative array* or *dictionary*) which allows to access arbitrary values by arbitrary keys. JavaScript's fundamental data structure is the *object*, a special type of map which only accepts strings as keys and has special semantics like prototypical inheritance, getters and setters and some further voodoo.

When using objects as maps, you have to remember that the key will be converted to a string value via `toString()`, which results in mapping `5` and `'5'` to the same value and all objects which don't overwrite the `toString()` method to the value indexed by `'[object Object]'`. You might also involuntarily access its inherited properties if you don't check `hasOwnProperty()`.

JavaScript's built-in *array* type does not help one bit: JavaScript arrays are not associative arrays, but just objects with a few more special properties. If you want to know why they can't be used as maps, [look here](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

## Eugene's Solution

[Eugene Lazutkin already described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent/368504#368504) the basic idea of using a custom hash function to generate unique strings which can be used to look up the associated values as properties of a dictionary object. This will most likely be the fastest solution, because objects are internally implemented as *hash tables*.

- **Note:** Hash tables (sometimes called *hash maps*) are a particular implementation of the map concept using a backing array and lookup via numeric hash values. The runtime environment might use other structures (such as *search trees* or *skip lists*) to implement JavaScript objects, but as objects are the fundamental data structure, they should be sufficiently optimised.

In order to get a unique hash value for arbitrary objects, one possibility is to use a global counter and cache the hash value in the object itself (for example, in a property named `__hash`).

A hash function which does this is and works for both primitive values and objects is:

```
function hash(value) {
    return (typeof value) + ' ' + (value instanceof Object ?
        (value.__hash || (value.__hash = ++arguments.callee.current)) :
        value.toString());
}

hash.current = 0;
```

This function can be used as described by Eugene. For convenience, we will further wrap it in a `Map` class.

## My `Map` implementation

The following implementation will additionally store the key-value-pairs in a doubly linked list in order to allow fast iteration over both keys and values. To supply your own hash function, you can overwrite the instance's `hash()` method after creation.

```
// Linking the key-value-pairs is optional.
// If no argument is provided, linkItems === undefined, i.e. !== false
// --> linking will be enabled
function Map(linkItems) {
    this.current = undefined;
    this.size = 0;

    if(linkItems === false)
        this.disableLinking();
}

Map.noop = function() {
    return this;
};

Map.illegal = function() {
    throw new Error("illegal operation for maps without linking");
};

// Map initialisation from an existing object
// doesn't add inherited properties if not explicitly instructed to:
// omitting foreignKeys means foreignKeys === undefined, i.e. == false
// --> inherited properties won't be added
Map.from = function(obj, foreignKeys) {
    var map = new Map;

    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(foreignKeys || obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            map.put(prop, obj[prop]);
    }

    return map;
};

Map.prototype.disableLinking = function() {
    this.link = Map.noop;
    this.unlink = Map.noop;
    this.disableLinking = Map.noop;
    this.next = Map.illegal;
    this.key = Map.illegal;
    this.value = Map.illegal;
    this.removeAll = Map.illegal;

    return this;
};

// Overwrite in Map instance if necessary
Map.prototype.hash = function(value) {
    return (typeof value) + ' ' + (value instanceof Object ?
        (value.__hash || (value.__hash = ++arguments.callee.current)) :
        value.toString());
};

Map.prototype.hash.current = 0;

// --- Mapping functions

Map.prototype.get = function(key) {
    var item = this[this.hash(key)];
    return item === undefined ? undefined : item.value;
};

Map.prototype.put = function(key, value) {
    var hash = this.hash(key);

    if(this[hash] === undefined) {
        var item = { key : key, value : value };
        this[hash] = item;

        this.link(item);
        ++this.size;
    }
    else this[hash].value = value;

    return this;
};

Map.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    var hash = this.hash(key);
    var item = this[hash];

    if(item !== undefined) {
        --this.size;
        this.unlink(item);

        delete this[hash];
    }

    return this;
};

// Only works if linked
Map.prototype.removeAll = function() {
    while(this.size)
        this.remove(this.key());

    return this;
};

// --- Linked list helper functions

Map.prototype.link = function(item) {
    if(this.size == 0) {
        item.prev = item;
        item.next = item;
        this.current = item;
    }
    else {
        item.prev = this.current.prev;
        item.prev.next = item;
        item.next = this.current;
        this.current.prev = item;
    }
};

Map.prototype.unlink = function(item) {
    if(this.size == 0)
        this.current = undefined;
    else {
        item.prev.next = item.next;
        item.next.prev = item.prev;
        if(item === this.current)
            this.current = item.next;
    }
};

// --- Iterator functions - only work if map is linked

Map.prototype.next = function() {
    this.current = this.current.next;
};

Map.prototype.key = function() {
    return this.current.key;
};

Map.prototype.value = function() {
    return this.current.value;
};
```

## Example

The following script,

```
var map = new Map;

map.put('spam', 'eggs').
    put('foo', 'bar').
    put('foo', 'baz').
    put({}, 'an object').
    put({}, 'another object').
    put(5, 'five').
    put(5, 'five again').
    put('5', 'another five');

for(var i = 0; i++ < map.size; map.next())
    document.writeln(map.hash(map.key()) + ' : ' + map.value());
```

generates this output:

```
string spam : eggs
string foo : baz
object 1 : an object
object 2 : another object
number 5 : five again
string 5 : another five
```

## Further considerations

[PEZ suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent/384517#384517) to overwrite the `toString()` method, presumably with our hash function. This is not feasible, because it doesn't work for primitive values (changing `toString()` for primitives is a *very* bad idea). If we want `toString()` to return meaningful values for arbitrary objects, we would have to modify `Object.prototype`, which some people (myself not included) consider *verboten*.

---

The current version of my `Map` implementation as well as other JavaScript goodies [can be obtained from here](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/map.js).

Comment: ES5 deprecates the use of callee (http://goo.gl/EeStE).  Instead, I suggest `Map._counter = 0`, and in the Map constructor do `this._hash = 'object ' + Map._counter++`.  Then hash() becomes `return (value && value._hash) || (typeof(value) + ' ' + String(value));`

Comment: Link to code is broken: http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/map.js

Comment: hi @Christoph, could you update your link to where I can find your Map implementation?

Comment: @jsc123: I'll look into that - for now you can get a dump of the repository at https://pikacode.com/mercurial.intuxication.org/js-hacks.tar.gz

Answer (score 84):

There are some really great solutions nowadays with external libraries:

- [collections.js](http://www.collectionsjs.com/)
- [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

JavaScript also has its language-provided `Map` as well.

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: This is the way to move forward to 21th century. Too bad that I found your post after finishing my code with some ugly home made Map. WEEE need more vote for your answer

Comment: Collections.js has some implementations, but I can't find any in underscore.js or lodash ... what were you referring to in underscore that would be useful?

Comment: @CodeBling no idea. i think i got it confused with the map function. i'm going to remove it from the answer.

Comment: That's fair. Anyone considering Collections.js should be aware that it modifies global Array, Function, Object and Regexp prototypes in a problematic fashion ([see the issues I encountered here](https://github.com/montagejs/collections/issues/162)). Although I was initially very pleased with collections.js (and thus this answer), the risks associated with using it were too high, so I dropped it. Only kriskowal's [v2 branch of collections.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/collections/tree/v2) (specifically, v2.0.2+) eliminates the global prototype modifications and is safe to use.

Answer (score 46):

According to ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), standard JavaScript has a Map implementation. More about which could be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Basic usage:

```
var myMap = new Map();
var keyString = "a string",
    keyObj = {},
    keyFunc = function () {};

// Setting the values
myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'");
myMap.set(keyObj, "value associated with keyObj");
myMap.set(keyFunc, "value associated with keyFunc");

myMap.size; // 3

// Getting the values
myMap.get(keyString);    // "value associated with 'a string'"
myMap.get(keyObj);       // "value associated with keyObj"
myMap.get(keyFunc);      // "value associated with keyFunc"
```

Comment: but does it use a hash-based implementation? obviously this is important for performance reasons, in cases where you would use a hashmap in other languages

Comment: It uses the underlying object id. So if you say `o = {}` and `map.set(o, 42)` and mutate `o`, then `map.get(o)` will still work

Answer (score 31):

Here is an easy and convenient way of using something similar to the Java map:

```
var map = {
              'map_name_1': map_value_1,
              'map_name_2': map_value_2,
              'map_name_3': map_value_3,
              'map_name_4': map_value_4
          }
```

And to get the value:

```
alert(map['map_name_1']);    // Gives the value of map_value_1

... etc. ...
```

Comment: This works for string keys only. I believe the OP was interested in using keys of any type.

Answer (score 25):

You can use ECMAScript 6 [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> - `WeakMap`s are key/value maps in which keys are objects.
> - `Map` objects are simple key/value maps. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

Be aware that neither is widely supported, but you can use [ECMAScript 6 Shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) (requires native ECMAScript 5 or [ECMAScript 5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)) to support `Map`, but not `WeakMap` ([see why](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim#weakmap-shim)).

Comment: In 2019 they are very well supported and have amazing methods! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Methods

Answer (score 13):

You'd have to store couplets of object/value pairs in some internal state:

```
HashMap = function(){
  this._dict = [];
}

HashMap.prototype._get = function(key){
  for(var i=0, couplet; couplet = this._dict[i]; i++){
    if(couplet[0] === key){
      return couplet;
    }
  }
}

HashMap.prototype.put = function(key, value){
  var couplet = this._get(key);
  if(couplet){
    couplet[1] = value;
  }else{
    this._dict.push([key, value]);
  }
  return this; // for chaining
}
HashMap.prototype.get = function(key){
  var couplet = this._get(key);
  if(couplet){
    return couplet[1];
  }
}
```

And use it as such:

```
var color = {}; // Unique object instance
var shape = {}; // Unique object instance
var map = new HashMap();
map.put(color, "blue");
map.put(shape, "round");
console.log("Item is", map.get(color), "and", map.get(shape));
```

Of course, this implementation is also somewhere along the lines of O(n). [Eugene's examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent/368504#368504) are the only way to get a hash that works with any sort of speed you'd expect from a real hash.

Another approach, along the lines of Eugene's answer is to somehow attach a unique ID to all objects. One of my favorite approaches is to take one of the built-in methods inherited from the Object superclass, replace it with a custom function passthrough and attach properties to that function object. If you were to rewrite my HashMap method to do this, it would look like:

```
HashMap = function(){
  this._dict = {};
}

HashMap.prototype._shared = {id: 1};
HashMap.prototype.put = function put(key, value){
  if(typeof key == "object"){
    if(!key.hasOwnProperty._id){
      key.hasOwnProperty = function(key){
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key);
      }
      key.hasOwnProperty._id = this._shared.id++;
    }
    this._dict[key.hasOwnProperty._id] = value;
  }else{
    this._dict[key] = value;
  }
  return this; // for chaining
}

HashMap.prototype.get = function get(key){
  if(typeof key == "object"){
    return this._dict[key.hasOwnProperty._id];
  }
  return this._dict[key];
}
```

This version appears to be only slightly faster, but in theory it will be significantly faster for large data sets.

Comment: An associative array, i.e. an array of 2-tuples, is a Map, not a HashMap; a HashMap is a Map that uses hashes for better performance.

Comment: True, but why split hairs on the topic? There's no way to create a true hash map in JavaScript since you can't get object memory addresses. And JavaScript's built-in object key/value pairs (used in my second example) may act as HashMaps, but not necessarily, as it is up to the runtime used in the browser as to how the lookup is implemented.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, none of the previous answers were good for my case: different key objects may have the same hash code. Therefore, I wrote a simple Java-like HashMap version:

```
function HashMap() {
    this.buckets = {};
}

HashMap.prototype.put = function(key, value) {
    var hashCode = key.hashCode();
    var bucket = this.buckets[hashCode];
    if (!bucket) {
        bucket = new Array();
        this.buckets[hashCode] = bucket;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < bucket.length; ++i) {
        if (bucket[i].key.equals(key)) {
            bucket[i].value = value;
            return;
        }
    }
    bucket.push({ key: key, value: value });
}

HashMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
    var hashCode = key.hashCode();
    var bucket = this.buckets[hashCode];
    if (!bucket) {
        return null;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < bucket.length; ++i) {
        if (bucket[i].key.equals(key)) {
            return bucket[i].value;
        }
    }
}

HashMap.prototype.keys = function() {
    var keys = new Array();
    for (var hashKey in this.buckets) {
        var bucket = this.buckets[hashKey];
        for (var i = 0; i < bucket.length; ++i) {
            keys.push(bucket[i].key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

HashMap.prototype.values = function() {
    var values = new Array();
    for (var hashKey in this.buckets) {
        var bucket = this.buckets[hashKey];
        for (var i = 0; i < bucket.length; ++i) {
            values.push(bucket[i].value);
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Note: key objects must "implement" the hashCode() and equals() methods.

Comment: The preference of `new Array()` over `[]` is to ensure the absolute Java-likeness of your code? :)

Answer (score 6):

I've implemented a JavaScript HashMap which code can be obtained from http://github.com/lambder/HashMapJS/tree/master

Here is the code:

```
/*
 =====================================================================
 @license MIT
 @author Lambder
 @copyright 2009 Lambder.
 @end
 =====================================================================
 */
var HashMap = function() {
  this.initialize();
}

HashMap.prototype = {
  hashkey_prefix: "<#HashMapHashkeyPerfix>",
  hashcode_field: "<#HashMapHashkeyPerfix>",

  initialize: function() {
    this.backing_hash = {};
    this.code = 0;
  },
  /*
   Maps value to key returning previous association
   */
  put: function(key, value) {
    var prev;
    if (key && value) {
      var hashCode = key[this.hashcode_field];
      if (hashCode) {
        prev = this.backing_hash[hashCode];
      } else {
        this.code += 1;
        hashCode = this.hashkey_prefix + this.code;
        key[this.hashcode_field] = hashCode;
      }
      this.backing_hash[hashCode] = value;
    }
    return prev;
  },
  /*
   Returns value associated with given key
   */
  get: function(key) {
    var value;
    if (key) {
      var hashCode = key[this.hashcode_field];
      if (hashCode) {
        value = this.backing_hash[hashCode];
      }
    }
    return value;
  },
  /*
   Deletes association by given key.
   Returns true if the association existed, false otherwise
   */
  del: function(key) {
    var success = false;
    if (key) {
      var hashCode = key[this.hashcode_field];
      if (hashCode) {
        var prev = this.backing_hash[hashCode];
        this.backing_hash[hashCode] = undefined;
        if(prev !== undefined)
          success = true;
      }
    }
    return success;
  }
}

//// Usage

// Creation

var my_map = new HashMap();

// Insertion

var a_key = {};
var a_value = {struct: "structA"};
var b_key = {};
var b_value = {struct: "structB"};
var c_key = {};
var c_value = {struct: "structC"};

my_map.put(a_key, a_value);
my_map.put(b_key, b_value);
var prev_b = my_map.put(b_key, c_value);

// Retrieval

if(my_map.get(a_key) !== a_value){
  throw("fail1")
}
if(my_map.get(b_key) !== c_value){
  throw("fail2")
}
if(prev_b !== b_value){
  throw("fail3")
}

// Deletion

var a_existed = my_map.del(a_key);
var c_existed = my_map.del(c_key);
var a2_existed = my_map.del(a_key);

if(a_existed !== true){
  throw("fail4")
}
if(c_existed !== false){
  throw("fail5")
}
if(a2_existed !== false){
  throw("fail6")
}
```

Comment: You code does not seem to work with putting the same object in multiple `HashMap`s.

Answer (score 5):

In ECMAScript 6 you can use [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).

Example:

```
var wm1 = new WeakMap(),
    wm2 = new WeakMap(),
    wm3 = new WeakMap();
var o1 = {},
    o2 = function(){},
    o3 = window;

wm1.set(o1, 37);
wm1.set(o2, "azerty");
wm2.set(o1, o2); // A value can be anything, including an object or a function
wm2.set(o3, undefined);
wm2.set(wm1, wm2); // Keys and values can be any objects. Even WeakMaps!

wm1.get(o2); // "azerty"
wm2.get(o2); // Undefined, because there is no value for o2 on wm2
wm2.get(o3); // Undefined, because that is the set value

wm1.has(o2); // True
wm2.has(o2); // False
wm2.has(o3); // True (even if the value itself is 'undefined')

wm3.set(o1, 37);
wm3.get(o1); // 37
wm3.clear();
wm3.get(o1); // Undefined, because wm3 was cleared and there is no value for o1 anymore

wm1.has(o1);   // True
wm1.delete(o1);
wm1.has(o1);   // False
```

But:

Because of references being weak, WeakMap keys are not enumerable (i.e. there is no method giving you a list of the keys).

Comment: oh praise jesus they're finally adding weak references to javascript. it's about time... +1 for that, but this would actually be awful to use because the references are weak

Answer (score 3):

Try my JavaScript hash table implementation: http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable

It looks for a hashCode() method of key objects, or you can supply a hashing function when creating a Hashtable object.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is not critical (e.g., the amount of keys is relatively small) and you don't want to pollute your (or maybe not your) objects with additional fields like `_hash`, `_id`, etc., then you can make use of the fact that [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) employs strict equality. Here is a simple implementation:

```
var Dict = (function(){
    // Internet Explorer 8 and earlier does not have any Array.prototype.indexOf
    function indexOfPolyfill(val) {
      for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (this[i] === val) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }

    function Dict(){
      this.keys = [];
      this.values = [];
      if (!this.keys.indexOf) {
        this.keys.indexOf = indexOfPolyfill;
      }
    };

    Dict.prototype.has = function(key){
      return this.keys.indexOf(key) != -1;
    };

    Dict.prototype.get = function(key, defaultValue){
      var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
      return index == -1 ? defaultValue : this.values[index];
    };

    Dict.prototype.set = function(key, value){
      var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
      if (index == -1) {
        this.keys.push(key);
        this.values.push(value);
      } else {
        var prevValue = this.values[index];
        this.values[index] = value;
        return prevValue;
      }
    };

    Dict.prototype.delete = function(key){
      var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
      if (index != -1) {
        this.keys.splice(index, 1);
        return this.values.splice(index, 1)[0];
      }
    };

    Dict.prototype.clear = function(){
      this.keys.splice(0, this.keys.length);
      this.values.splice(0, this.values.length);
    };

    return Dict;
})();
```

Example of usage:

```
var a = {}, b = {},
    c = { toString: function(){ return '1'; } },
    d = 1, s = '1', u = undefined, n = null,
    dict = new Dict();

// Keys and values can be anything
dict.set(a, 'a');
dict.set(b, 'b');
dict.set(c, 'c');
dict.set(d, 'd');
dict.set(s, 's');
dict.set(u, 'u');
dict.set(n, 'n');

dict.get(a); // 'a'
dict.get(b); // 'b'
dict.get(s); // 's'
dict.get(u); // 'u'
dict.get(n); // 'n'
// etc.
```

Comparing to ECMAScript 6 WeakMap, it has two issues: O(n) search time and non-weakness (i.e., it will cause memory leak if you don't use `delete` or `clear` to release keys).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have a built-in map/hashmap. It should be called an [associative array](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

`hash["X"]` is equal to `hash.X`, but it allows "X" as a string variable.
In other words, `hash[x]` is functionally equal to `eval("hash."+x.toString())`.

It is more similar to object.properties rather than key-value mapping.
If you are looking for a better key/value mapping in JavaScript, please use [the Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 2):

My 'Map' implementation, derived from [Christoph's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent/383540#383540):

Example usage:

```
var map = new Map();  // Creates an "in-memory" map
var map = new Map("storageId");  // Creates a map that is loaded/persisted using html5 storage
```

---

```
function Map(storageId) {
    this.current = undefined;
    this.size = 0;
    this.storageId = storageId;
    if (this.storageId) {
        this.keys = new Array();
        this.disableLinking();
    }
}

Map.noop = function() {
    return this;
};

Map.illegal = function() {
    throw new Error("illegal operation for maps without linking");
};

// Map initialisation from an existing object
// doesn't add inherited properties if not explicitly instructed to:
// omitting foreignKeys means foreignKeys === undefined, i.e. == false
// --> inherited properties won't be added
Map.from = function(obj, foreignKeys) {
    var map = new Map;
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(foreignKeys || obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            map.put(prop, obj[prop]);
    }
    return map;
};

Map.prototype.disableLinking = function() {
    this.link = Map.noop;
    this.unlink = Map.noop;
    this.disableLinking = Map.noop;

    this.next = Map.illegal;
    this.key = Map.illegal;
    this.value = Map.illegal;
//    this.removeAll = Map.illegal;


    return this;
};

// Overwrite in Map instance if necessary
Map.prototype.hash = function(value) {
    return (typeof value) + ' ' + (value instanceof Object ?
        (value.__hash || (value.__hash = ++arguments.callee.current)) :
        value.toString());
};

Map.prototype.hash.current = 0;

// --- Mapping functions

Map.prototype.get = function(key) {
    var item = this[this.hash(key)];
    if (item === undefined) {
        if (this.storageId) {
            try {
                var itemStr = localStorage.getItem(this.storageId + key);
                if (itemStr && itemStr !== 'undefined') {
                    item = JSON.parse(itemStr);
                    this[this.hash(key)] = item;
                    this.keys.push(key);
                    ++this.size;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return item === undefined ? undefined : item.value;
};

Map.prototype.put = function(key, value) {
    var hash = this.hash(key);

    if(this[hash] === undefined) {
        var item = { key : key, value : value };
        this[hash] = item;

        this.link(item);
        ++this.size;
    }
    else this[hash].value = value;
    if (this.storageId) {
        this.keys.push(key);
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(this.storageId + key, JSON.stringify(this[hash]));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

Map.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    var hash = this.hash(key);
    var item = this[hash];
    if(item !== undefined) {
        --this.size;
        this.unlink(item);

        delete this[hash];
    }
    if (this.storageId) {
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(this.storageId + key, undefined);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

// Only works if linked
Map.prototype.removeAll = function() {
    if (this.storageId) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.keys.length; i++) {
            this.remove(this.keys[i]);
        }
        this.keys.length = 0;
    } else {
        while(this.size)
            this.remove(this.key());
    }
    return this;
};

// --- Linked list helper functions

Map.prototype.link = function(item) {
    if (this.storageId) {
        return;
    }
    if(this.size == 0) {
        item.prev = item;
        item.next = item;
        this.current = item;
    }
    else {
        item.prev = this.current.prev;
        item.prev.next = item;
        item.next = this.current;
        this.current.prev = item;
    }
};

Map.prototype.unlink = function(item) {
    if (this.storageId) {
        return;
    }
    if(this.size == 0)
        this.current = undefined;
    else {
        item.prev.next = item.next;
        item.next.prev = item.prev;
        if(item === this.current)
            this.current = item.next;
    }
};

// --- Iterator functions - only work if map is linked

Map.prototype.next = function() {
    this.current = this.current.next;
};

Map.prototype.key = function() {
    if (this.storageId) {
        return undefined;
    } else {
        return this.current.key;
    }
};

Map.prototype.value = function() {
    if (this.storageId) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return this.current.value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding yet another solution: `HashMap` is pretty much the first class I ported from Java to JavaScript. You could say there is a lot of overhead, but the implementation is almost 100% equal to Java's implementation and includes all interfaces and subclasses.

The project can be found here: https://github.com/Airblader/jsava
I'll also attach the (current) source code for the HashMap class, but as stated it also depends on the super class, etc. The OOP framework used is qooxdoo.

Please note that this code is already out-dated and refer to the GitHub project for the current work. As of writing this, there is also an `ArrayList` implementation.

```
qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap', {
    extend: jsava.util.AbstractMap,
    implement: [jsava.util.Map, jsava.io.Serializable, jsava.lang.Cloneable],

    construct: function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ),
            initialCapacity = this.self( arguments ).DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY,
            loadFactor = this.self( arguments ).DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR;

        switch( args.length ) {
            case 1:
                if( qx.Class.implementsInterface( args[0], jsava.util.Map ) ) {
                    initialCapacity = Math.max( ((args[0].size() / this.self( arguments ).DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR) | 0) + 1,
                        this.self( arguments ).DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY );
                    loadFactor = this.self( arguments ).DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR;
                } else {
                    initialCapacity = args[0];
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                initialCapacity = args[0];
                loadFactor = args[1];
                break;
        }

        if( initialCapacity < 0 ) {
            throw new jsava.lang.IllegalArgumentException( 'Illegal initial capacity: ' + initialCapacity );
        }
        if( initialCapacity > this.self( arguments ).MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ) {
            initialCapacity = this.self( arguments ).MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
        }
        if( loadFactor <= 0 || isNaN( loadFactor ) ) {
            throw new jsava.lang.IllegalArgumentException( 'Illegal load factor: ' + loadFactor );
        }

        var capacity = 1;
        while( capacity < initialCapacity ) {
            capacity <<= 1;
        }

        this._loadFactor = loadFactor;
        this._threshold = (capacity * loadFactor) | 0;
        this._table = jsava.JsavaUtils.emptyArrayOfGivenSize( capacity, null );
        this._init();
    },

    statics: {
        serialVersionUID: 1,

        DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY: 16,
        MAXIMUM_CAPACITY: 1 << 30,
        DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR: 0.75,

        _hash: function (hash) {
            hash ^= (hash >>> 20) ^ (hash >>> 12);
            return hash ^ (hash >>> 7) ^ (hash >>> 4);
        },

        _indexFor: function (hashCode, length) {
            return hashCode & (length - 1);
        },

        Entry: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.Entry', {
            extend: jsava.lang.Object,
            implement: [jsava.util.Map.Entry],

            construct: function (hash, key, value, nextEntry) {
                this._value = value;
                this._next = nextEntry;
                this._key = key;
                this._hash = hash;
            },

            members: {
                _key: null,
                _value: null,
                /** @type jsava.util.HashMap.Entry */
                _next: null,
                /** @type Number */
                _hash: 0,

                getKey: function () {
                    return this._key;
                },

                getValue: function () {
                    return this._value;
                },

                setValue: function (newValue) {
                    var oldValue = this._value;
                    this._value = newValue;
                    return oldValue;
                },

                equals: function (obj) {
                    if( obj === null || !qx.Class.implementsInterface( obj, jsava.util.HashMap.Entry ) ) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    /** @type jsava.util.HashMap.Entry */
                    var entry = obj,
                        key1 = this.getKey(),
                        key2 = entry.getKey();
                    if( key1 === key2 || (key1 !== null && key1.equals( key2 )) ) {
                        var value1 = this.getValue(),
                            value2 = entry.getValue();
                        if( value1 === value2 || (value1 !== null && value1.equals( value2 )) ) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                },

                hashCode: function () {
                    return (this._key === null ? 0 : this._key.hashCode()) ^
                        (this._value === null ? 0 : this._value.hashCode());
                },

                toString: function () {
                    return this.getKey() + '=' + this.getValue();
                },

                /**
                 * This method is invoked whenever the value in an entry is
                 * overwritten by an invocation of put(k,v) for a key k that's already
                 * in the HashMap.
                 */
                _recordAccess: function (map) {
                },

                /**
                 * This method is invoked whenever the entry is
                 * removed from the table.
                 */
                _recordRemoval: function (map) {
                }
            }
        } )
    },

    members: {
        /** @type jsava.util.HashMap.Entry[] */
        _table: null,
        /** @type Number */
        _size: 0,
        /** @type Number */
        _threshold: 0,
        /** @type Number */
        _loadFactor: 0,
        /** @type Number */
        _modCount: 0,
        /** @implements jsava.util.Set */
        __entrySet: null,

        /**
         * Initialization hook for subclasses. This method is called
         * in all constructors and pseudo-constructors (clone, readObject)
         * after HashMap has been initialized but before any entries have
         * been inserted.  (In the absence of this method, readObject would
         * require explicit knowledge of subclasses.)
         */
        _init: function () {
        },

        size: function () {
            return this._size;
        },

        isEmpty: function () {
            return this._size === 0;
        },

        get: function (key) {
            if( key === null ) {
                return this.__getForNullKey();
            }

            var hash = this.self( arguments )._hash( key.hashCode() );
            for( var entry = this._table[this.self( arguments )._indexFor( hash, this._table.length )];
                 entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                /** @type jsava.lang.Object */
                var k;
                if( entry._hash === hash && ((k = entry._key) === key || key.equals( k )) ) {
                    return entry._value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        },

        __getForNullKey: function () {
            for( var entry = this._table[0]; entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                if( entry._key === null ) {
                    return entry._value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        },

        containsKey: function (key) {
            return this._getEntry( key ) !== null;
        },

        _getEntry: function (key) {
            var hash = (key === null) ? 0 : this.self( arguments )._hash( key.hashCode() );
            for( var entry = this._table[this.self( arguments )._indexFor( hash, this._table.length )];
                 entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                /** @type jsava.lang.Object */
                var k;
                if( entry._hash === hash
                    && ( ( k = entry._key ) === key || ( key !== null && key.equals( k ) ) ) ) {
                    return entry;
                }
            }

            return null;
        },

        put: function (key, value) {
            if( key === null ) {
                return this.__putForNullKey( value );
            }

            var hash = this.self( arguments )._hash( key.hashCode() ),
                i = this.self( arguments )._indexFor( hash, this._table.length );
            for( var entry = this._table[i]; entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                /** @type jsava.lang.Object */
                var k;
                if( entry._hash === hash && ( (k = entry._key) === key || key.equals( k ) ) ) {
                    var oldValue = entry._value;
                    entry._value = value;
                    entry._recordAccess( this );
                    return oldValue;
                }
            }

            this._modCount++;
            this._addEntry( hash, key, value, i );
            return null;
        },

        __putForNullKey: function (value) {
            for( var entry = this._table[0]; entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                if( entry._key === null ) {
                    var oldValue = entry._value;
                    entry._value = value;
                    entry._recordAccess( this );
                    return oldValue;
                }
            }

            this._modCount++;
            this._addEntry( 0, null, value, 0 );
            return null;
        },

        __putForCreate: function (key, value) {
            var hash = (key === null) ? 0 : this.self( arguments )._hash( key.hashCode() ),
                i = this.self( arguments )._indexFor( hash, this._table.length );
            for( var entry = this._table[i]; entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                /** @type jsava.lang.Object */
                var k;
                if( entry._hash === hash
                    && ( (k = entry._key) === key || ( key !== null && key.equals( k ) ) ) ) {
                    entry._value = value;
                    return;
                }
            }

            this._createEntry( hash, key, value, i );
        },

        __putAllForCreate: function (map) {
            var iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
                var entry = iterator.next();
                this.__putForCreate( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            }
        },

        _resize: function (newCapacity) {
            var oldTable = this._table,
                oldCapacity = oldTable.length;
            if( oldCapacity === this.self( arguments ).MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ) {
                this._threshold = Number.MAX_VALUE;
                return;
            }

            var newTable = jsava.JsavaUtils.emptyArrayOfGivenSize( newCapacity, null );
            this._transfer( newTable );
            this._table = newTable;
            this._threshold = (newCapacity * this._loadFactor) | 0;
        },

        _transfer: function (newTable) {
            var src = this._table,
                newCapacity = newTable.length;
            for( var j = 0; j < src.length; j++ ) {
                var entry = src[j];
                if( entry !== null ) {
                    src[j] = null;
                    do {
                        var next = entry._next,
                            i = this.self( arguments )._indexFor( entry._hash, newCapacity );
                        entry._next = newTable[i];
                        newTable[i] = entry;
                        entry = next;
                    } while( entry !== null );
                }
            }
        },

        putAll: function (map) {
            var numKeyToBeAdded = map.size();
            if( numKeyToBeAdded === 0 ) {
                return;
            }

            if( numKeyToBeAdded > this._threshold ) {
                var targetCapacity = (numKeyToBeAdded / this._loadFactor + 1) | 0;
                if( targetCapacity > this.self( arguments ).MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ) {
                    targetCapacity = this.self( arguments ).MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
                }

                var newCapacity = this._table.length;
                while( newCapacity < targetCapacity ) {
                    newCapacity <<= 1;
                }
                if( newCapacity > this._table.length ) {
                    this._resize( newCapacity );
                }
            }

            var iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
                var entry = iterator.next();
                this.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            }
        },

        remove: function (key) {
            var entry = this._removeEntryForKey( key );
            return entry === null ? null : entry._value;
        },

        _removeEntryForKey: function (key) {
            var hash = (key === null) ? 0 : this.self( arguments )._hash( key.hashCode() ),
                i = this.self( arguments )._indexFor( hash, this._table.length ),
                prev = this._table[i],
                entry = prev;

            while( entry !== null ) {
                var next = entry._next,
                    /** @type jsava.lang.Object */
                        k;
                if( entry._hash === hash
                    && ( (k = entry._key) === key || ( key !== null && key.equals( k ) ) ) ) {
                    this._modCount++;
                    this._size--;
                    if( prev === entry ) {
                        this._table[i] = next;
                    } else {
                        prev._next = next;
                    }
                    entry._recordRemoval( this );
                    return entry;
                }
                prev = entry;
                entry = next;
            }

            return entry;
        },

        _removeMapping: function (obj) {
            if( obj === null || !qx.Class.implementsInterface( obj, jsava.util.Map.Entry ) ) {
                return null;
            }

            /** @implements jsava.util.Map.Entry */
            var entry = obj,
                key = entry.getKey(),
                hash = (key === null) ? 0 : this.self( arguments )._hash( key.hashCode() ),
                i = this.self( arguments )._indexFor( hash, this._table.length ),
                prev = this._table[i],
                e = prev;

            while( e !== null ) {
                var next = e._next;
                if( e._hash === hash && e.equals( entry ) ) {
                    this._modCount++;
                    this._size--;
                    if( prev === e ) {
                        this._table[i] = next;
                    } else {
                        prev._next = next;
                    }
                    e._recordRemoval( this );
                    return e;
                }
                prev = e;
                e = next;
            }

            return e;
        },

        clear: function () {
            this._modCount++;
            var table = this._table;
            for( var i = 0; i < table.length; i++ ) {
                table[i] = null;
            }
            this._size = 0;
        },

        containsValue: function (value) {
            if( value === null ) {
                return this.__containsNullValue();
            }

            var table = this._table;
            for( var i = 0; i < table.length; i++ ) {
                for( var entry = table[i]; entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                    if( value.equals( entry._value ) ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        },

        __containsNullValue: function () {
            var table = this._table;
            for( var i = 0; i < table.length; i++ ) {
                for( var entry = table[i]; entry !== null; entry = entry._next ) {
                    if( entry._value === null ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        },

        clone: function () {
            /** @type jsava.util.HashMap */
            var result = null;
            try {
                result = this.base( arguments );
            } catch( e ) {
                if( !qx.Class.isSubClassOf( e.constructor, jsava.lang.CloneNotSupportedException ) ) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }

            result._table = jsava.JsavaUtils.emptyArrayOfGivenSize( this._table.length, null );
            result.__entrySet = null;
            result._modCount = 0;
            result._size = 0;
            result._init();
            result.__putAllForCreate( this );

            return result;
        },

        _addEntry: function (hash, key, value, bucketIndex) {
            var entry = this._table[bucketIndex];
            this._table[bucketIndex] = new (this.self( arguments ).Entry)( hash, key, value, entry );
            if( this._size++ >= this._threshold ) {
                this._resize( 2 * this._table.length );
            }
        },

        _createEntry: function (hash, key, value, bucketIndex) {
            var entry = this._table[bucketIndex];
            this._table[bucketIndex] = new (this.self( arguments ).Entry)( hash, key, value, entry );
            this._size++;
        },

        keySet: function () {
            var keySet = this._keySet;
            return keySet !== null ? keySet : ( this._keySet = new this.KeySet( this ) );
        },

        values: function () {
            var values = this._values;
            return values !== null ? values : ( this._values = new this.Values( this ) );
        },

        entrySet: function () {
            return this.__entrySet0();
        },

        __entrySet0: function () {
            var entrySet = this.__entrySet;
            return entrySet !== null ? entrySet : ( this.__entrySet = new this.EntrySet( this ) );
        },

        /** @private */
        HashIterator: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.HashIterator', {
            extend: jsava.lang.Object,
            implement: [jsava.util.Iterator],

            type: 'abstract',

            /** @protected */
            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.__thisHashMap = thisHashMap;
                this._expectedModCount = this.__thisHashMap._modCount;
                if( this.__thisHashMap._size > 0 ) {
                    var table = this.__thisHashMap._table;
                    while( this._index < table.length && ( this._next = table[this._index++] ) === null ) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
            },

            members: {
                __thisHashMap: null,

                /** @type jsava.util.HashMap.Entry */
                _next: null,
                /** @type Number */
                _expectedModCount: 0,
                /** @type Number */
                _index: 0,
                /** @type jsava.util.HashMap.Entry */
                _current: null,

                hasNext: function () {
                    return this._next !== null;
                },

                _nextEntry: function () {
                    if( this.__thisHashMap._modCount !== this._expectedModCount ) {
                        throw new jsava.lang.ConcurrentModificationException();
                    }

                    var entry = this._next;
                    if( entry === null ) {
                        throw new jsava.lang.NoSuchElementException();
                    }

                    if( (this._next = entry._next) === null ) {
                        var table = this.__thisHashMap._table;
                        while( this._index < table.length && ( this._next = table[this._index++] ) === null ) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    }

                    this._current = entry;
                    return entry;
                },

                remove: function () {
                    if( this._current === null ) {
                        throw new jsava.lang.IllegalStateException();
                    }

                    if( this.__thisHashMap._modCount !== this._expectedModCount ) {
                        throw new jsava.lang.ConcurrentModificationException();
                    }

                    var key = this._current._key;
                    this._current = null;
                    this.__thisHashMap._removeEntryForKey( key );
                    this._expectedModCount = this.__thisHashMap._modCount;
                }
            }
        } ),

        _newKeyIterator: function () {
            return new this.KeyIterator( this );
        },

        _newValueIterator: function () {
            return new this.ValueIterator( this );
        },

        _newEntryIterator: function () {
            return new this.EntryIterator( this );
        },

        /** @private */
        ValueIterator: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.ValueIterator', {
            extend: jsava.util.HashMap.HashIterator,

            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.base( arguments, thisHashMap );
            },

            members: {
                next: function () {
                    return this._nextEntry()._value;
                }
            }
        } ),

        /** @private */
        KeyIterator: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.KeyIterator', {
            extend: jsava.util.HashMap.HashIterator,

            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.base( arguments, thisHashMap );
            },

            members: {
                next: function () {
                    return this._nextEntry().getKey();
                }
            }
        } ),

        /** @private */
        EntryIterator: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.EntryIterator', {
            extend: jsava.util.HashMap.HashIterator,

            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.base( arguments, thisHashMap );
            },

            members: {
                next: function () {
                    return this._nextEntry();
                }
            }
        } ),

        /** @private */
        KeySet: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.KeySet', {
            extend: jsava.util.AbstractSet,

            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.base( arguments );
                this.__thisHashMap = thisHashMap;
            },

            members: {
                __thisHashMap: null,

                iterator: function () {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._newKeyIterator();
                },

                size: function () {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._size;
                },

                contains: function (obj) {
                    return this.__thisHashMap.containsKey( obj );
                },

                remove: function (obj) {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._removeEntryForKey( obj ) !== null;
                },

                clear: function () {
                    this.__thisHashMap.clear();
                }
            }
        } ),

        /** @private */
        Values: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.Values', {
            extend: jsava.util.AbstractCollection,

            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.base( arguments );
                this.__thisHashMap = thisHashMap;
            },

            members: {
                __thisHashMap: null,

                iterator: function () {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._newValueIterator();
                },

                size: function () {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._size;
                },

                contains: function (obj) {
                    return this.__thisHashMap.containsValue( obj );
                },

                clear: function () {
                    this.__thisHashMap.clear();
                }
            }
        } ),

        /** @private */
        EntrySet: qx.Class.define( 'jsava.util.HashMap.EntrySet', {
            extend: jsava.util.AbstractSet,

            construct: function (thisHashMap) {
                this.base( arguments );
                this.__thisHashMap = thisHashMap;
            },

            members: {
                __thisHashMap: null,

                iterator: function () {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._newEntryIterator();
                },

                size: function () {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._size;
                },

                contains: function (obj) {
                    if( obj === null || !qx.Class.implementsInterface( obj, jsava.util.Map.Entry ) ) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    /** @implements jsava.util.Map.Entry */
                    var entry = obj,
                        candidate = this.__thisHashMap._getEntry( entry.getKey() );
                    return candidate !== null && candidate.equals( entry );
                },

                remove: function (obj) {
                    return this.__thisHashMap._removeMapping( obj ) !== null;
                },

                clear: function () {
                    this.__thisHashMap.clear();
                }
            }
        } )
    }
} );
```

Comment: Hmm interesting approach.. have you considered trying out an automated approach? that is, running a Java-to-javascript compiler on the source code for the current java implementation?

Comment: Nope :) This is just a fun project for me and there were quite a few things were I couldn't simply "copy" code. I'm not aware of Java-to-Javascript compilers, though I would believe they exist. I'm not sure how well they would translate this. I'm fairly certain they wouldn't produce good-quality code in any case, though.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I was thinking of [Google Web Toolkit's](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-4/wiki/JavaToJavaScriptCompiler) compiler, but it seems they ended up doing what you are doing here for the core libraries: "The GWT compiler supports the vast majority of the Java language itself. The GWT runtime library emulates a relevant subset of the Java runtime library.". Maybe something to look at to see how others solved the same problem!

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure Google's solution is far beyond mine, but then again, I'm just having some fun playing around. Unfortunately, the source code seems to have been revoked(?), at least I can't browse it and the interesting links seem to be dead. Too bad, I would've loved to look at it.

Comment: Having fun playing around is the best way to learn =). thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty robust
solution: https://github.com/flesler/hashmap

It will even work well for functions and objects that look identical. The only hack it uses is adding an obscure member to an object to identify it. If your program doesn't overwrite that obscure variable (it's something like *hashid*), you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another map implementation by me. With randomizer, 'generics' and 'iterator' =)

```
var HashMap = function (TKey, TValue) {
    var db = [];
    var keyType, valueType;

    (function () {
        keyType = TKey;
        valueType = TValue;
    })();

    var getIndexOfKey = function (key) {
        if (typeof key !== keyType)
            throw new Error('Type of key should be ' + keyType);
        for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            if (db[i][0] == key)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    this.add = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof key !== keyType) {
            throw new Error('Type of key should be ' + keyType);
        } else if (typeof value !== valueType) {
            throw new Error('Type of value should be ' + valueType);
        }
        var index = getIndexOfKey(key);
        if (index === -1)
            db.push([key, value]);
        else
            db[index][1] = value;
        return this;
    }

    this.get = function (key) {
        if (typeof key !== keyType || db.length === 0)
            return null;
        for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            if (db[i][0] == key)
                return db[i][1];
        }
        return null;
    }

    this.size = function () {
        return db.length;
    }

    this.keys = function () {
        if (db.length === 0)
            return [];
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            result.push(db[i][0]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    this.values = function () {
        if (db.length === 0)
            return [];
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            result.push(db[i][1]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    this.randomize = function () {
        if (db.length === 0)
            return this;
        var currentIndex = db.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex--;
            temporaryValue = db[currentIndex];
            db[currentIndex] = db[randomIndex];
            db[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }
        return this;
    }

    this.iterate = function (callback) {
        if (db.length === 0)
            return false;
        for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            callback(db[i][0], db[i][1]);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var a = new HashMap("string", "number");
a.add('test', 1132)
 .add('test14', 666)
 .add('1421test14', 12312666)
 .iterate(function (key, value) {console.log('a['+key+']='+value)});
/*
a[test]=1132
a[test14]=666
a[1421test14]=12312666 
*/
a.randomize();
/*
a[1421test14]=12312666
a[test]=1132
a[test14]=666
*/
```

Comment: What is the idea? What is the important difference in terms of how it works? What is the consequence (performance, better/worse worst-case performance, scaling, etc.)?