# Javascript: var map = {}; var list = [];

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can someone tell me what exactly the two above lines of javascript do? And more importantly, what it's called so I can search some javascript references to learn about it? I assume they are both creating some form of an array that objects can be added to...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates an empty dictionary in `map` and an empty array in `list`.

Read up on these structures at http://www.geocities.com/schools_ring/ArrayAndHash.html.

Comment: Your link calls javascript objects hash tables, you call them dictionaries. Just call them  objects - calling them something else is misleading at best - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent#383540

Answer (score 8):

Curly braces are syntax for creating a Javascript object (which is really a glorified collection of key/value pairs); the brackets make a resizable array.

These are called literals, and they're a handy shortcut to help you make objects and arrays without a lot of typing (good, because you use them all the time). Many other programming languages have similar literal syntax for maps and arrays.