# Is array both associative and indexed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, associative

Can an array in JavaScript be associative AND indexed?

I'd like to be able to lookup an item in the array by its position or a key value.

Comment: this is pretty old, but you can use Object.keys(array) to get the keys in order

Comment: You are a PHP programmer :)

Answer (score 30):

There are no such things as associative arrays in Javascript. You can use object literals, which *look* like associative arrays, but they have unordered properties. Regular Javascript arrays are based on integer indexes, and can't be associative.

For example, with this object:

```
var params = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 0,
    other: 2
};
```

You can access properties from the object, for example:

```
params["foo"];
```

And you can also iterate over the object using the `for...in` statement:

```
for(var v in params) {
    //v is equal to the currently iterated property
}
```

However, there is no strict rule on the order of property iteration - two iterations of your object literal could return the properties in different orders.

Comment: Actually, JavaScript arrays can have non-integer indices as well. It just doesn't have much in the way of methods for dealing with them.

Comment: You mean like a string? in that case it isn't an array, just an object with properties.

Comment: Nosredna: JS arrays do not have key indices, those JS objects are considered object literals. 

so:

foo["bar"] = 1;
foo.bar === foo["bar"]; //true
foo["bar"] === foo[0]; //false

This is one of the many subtle quirks about JS that throw people off easily.

Comment: JavaScript Objects, including Arrays, have *only* string indices. `a[1]` is actually saying `a['1']`.

Comment: The latest MDN documentation makes it quiet clear that Array index must be integers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 22):

After reading the [Wikipedia definition of associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), I'm going to break with traditional JavaScript lore and say, "yes, JavaScript does have associative arrays." With JavaScript arrays, you can add, reassign, remove, and lookup values by their keys (and the keys can be quoted strings), which is what Wikipedia says associative arrays should be able to do.

However, you seem to be asking something different--whether you can look up the same value by either index or key. That's not a requirement of associative arrays (see the Wikipedia article.) Associative arrays don't have to give you the ability to get a value by index.

[JavaScript arrays are very closely akin to JavaScript objects.](http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/how-weird-are-javascript-arrays/)

```
  arr=[];
  arr[0]="zero";
  arr[1]="one";
  arr[2]="two";
  arr["fancy"]="what?";
```

Yes, that's an array, and yes, you can get away with non-numeric indices. (If you're curious, after all this, arr.length is 3.)

In most cases, I think you should stick to numeric indices when you use arrays. That what most programmers expect, I think.

The link is to my blog post about the subject.

Comment: You were right when you said "And you can have an array with non-numeric indices". It slipped my mind somehow, but I know this fact.

Comment: To be pedantic, "fancy" is not an index in the array, but an attribute of the array instance object.

Comment: Yeah, good point. That's why I say that arrays are closely related to objects in JavaScript.

Comment: @BaroqueBobcat: to be really pedantic :) indices in the array are just properties ("attributes") of the array instance object; an array just treats specially those properties which are the string form of an integer with regards to the length property.

Comment: It's not pedantic at all. It's an incredibly important distinction, made evident when you start trying to serialise your array into, say, JSON. The value with a non-numeric key is _not_ part of the array data. (And strictly speaking, you're breaking your array by not using `.push()`.)

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because while it might be possible to use syntaxt that looks like an array, this is not proper javascript nor a proper array. Your answer is good for reference, but should have a clear reminder that this is NOT how you'd conventionally use arrays.

Comment: Arrays should be able to be indexed so when it's iterated, it is returned in order, but here it's not the case.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but to be clear, JavaScript does not have associative arrays and you cannot pass a string index to an array. What you are talking about here is an object with keys.

Answer (score 9):

Native JS objects only accept strings as property names, which is true [even for numeric array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453765/javascript-arrays-and-type-conversion-inconsistencies/453773#453773); arrays differ from vanilla objects only insofar as most JS implementations will store numerically indexed properties differently (ie in an actual array as long as they are dense) and setting them will trigger additional operations (eg adjustment of the `length` property).

If you're looking for a map which accepts arbitrary keys, you'll have to use a [non-native implementation](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/map.js). The script is intended for fast iteration and not random-access by numeric indices, so it might nor be what you're looking for.

A barebones implementation of a map which would do what you're asking for could look like this:

```
function Map() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.store = {};
}

Map.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return this.store.hasOwnProperty(key) ?
        this.store[key] : undefined;
};

Map.prototype.put = function(key, value, index) {
    if(arguments.length < 3) {
        if(this.store.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.store[key].value = value;
            return this;
        }

        index = this.length;
    }
    else if(index >>> 0 !== index || index >= 0xffffffff)
        throw new Error('illegal index argument');

    if(index >= this.length)
        this.length = index + 1;

    this[index] = this.store[key] =
        { index : index, key : key, value : value };

    return this;
};
```

The `index` argument of `put()` is optional.

You can access the values in a map `map` either by key or index via

```
map.get('key').value
map[2].value
```

Comment: +1, but I would lose "numerically indexed properties will be stored differently": that's not necessarily the case, and isn't required by the spec.

Comment: How do you put? map.put('key','value') and map[2].value = val ?

Comment: `map.put('key','value')` for appending a value and `map.put('key','value', 42)` for inserting a value at a given position; `map[42].value = 'value'` will also work (ie replace the value of an existing key-value-pair), but you can't change the key or index of the entry or add new entries this way

Answer (score 7):

```
var myArray = Array();
myArray["first"] = "Object1";
myArray["second"] = "Object2";
myArray["third"] = "Object3";

Object.keys(myArray);              // returns ["first", "second", "third"]
Object.keys(myArray).length;       // returns 3
```

if you want the first element then you can use it like so:

```
myArray[Object.keys(myArray)[0]];  // returns "Object1"
```

Answer (score 5):

The order in which objects appear in an associative javascript array is not defined, and will differ across different implementations.  For that reason you can't really count on a given associative key to always be at the same index.

EDIT:

as Perspx points out, there aren't really true associative arrays in javascript.  The statement `foo["bar"]` is just syntactic sugar for `foo.bar`

If you trust the browser to maintain the order of elements in an object, you could write a function

```
function valueForIndex(obj, index) {

    var i = 0;
    for (var key in obj) {

        if (i++ == index)
            return obj[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is a true, in practice all major browsers loop over the properties of an object in the order in which they were defined. This is not in the spec, of course, but it's worth a mention.

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays. Your answer is talking about objects, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stuff = [];
stuff[0] = "foo";
stuff.bar = stuff[0]; // stuff.bar can be stuff["bar"] if you prefer
var key = "bar";
alert(stuff[0] + ", " + stuff[key]); // shows "foo, foo"
```

Comment: but then stuff.length would not be 1 anymore since you added .bar right? thus looping through by index wouldnt really work anymore..

Comment: No - adding a named property doesn't increase the length; only adding an element by numeric index increases length. Adding "stuff[1000] = 'blah'" would cause the length to increase to 1001, even though only two numerically-indexed elements and one named property have actually been added. Fun isn't it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I came here to wanting to know if this is bad practice or not, and instead found a lot of people appearing not to understand the question.

I wanted to have a data structure that was ordered but could be indexed by key, so that it wouldn't require iteration for every lookup.

In practical terms this is quite simple, but I still haven't read anything on whether it's a terrible practice or not.

```
var roygbiv = [];
var colour = { key : "red", hex : "#FF0000" };
roygbiv.push(colour);
roygbiv[colour.key] = colour;
...
console.log("Hex colours of the rainbow in order:");
for (var i = 0; i < roygbiv.length; i++) {
    console.log(roygbiv[i].key + " is " + roygbiv[i].hex);
}

// input = "red";
console.log("Hex code of input colour:");
console.log(roygbiv[input].hex);
```

The important thing is to never change the value of array[index] or array[key] directly once the object is set up or the values will no longer match.  If the array contains objects you can change the properties of those objects and you will be able to access the changed properties by either method.

Comment: This is the approach I took, but with a syntax showing the association at assignment which I found more to my liking `aSignals[aSignals.length] = aSignals['fooBar'] = { 'sKey': 'foobBar', ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the answers given you can actually accomplish what you are saying with getters and setters. For example:

```
var a = [1];
//This makes a["blah"] refer to a[0]
a.__defineGetter__("blah", function(){return this[0]});
//This makes a["blah"] = 5 actually store 5 into a[0]
a.__defineSetter__("blah", function(val){ this[0] = val});

alert(a["blah"]); // emits 1
a["blah"] = 5;
alert(a[0]); // emits 5
```

Is this what you are looking for? i think theres a different more modern way to do getters and setters but cant remember.

Comment: Oh and if you are going to do this in a loop you will likely need closures btw... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The tide has changed on this one. Now you can do that... and MORE! Using Harmony Proxies you could definitely solve this problem in many ways.

You'll have to verify that your targeted environments support this with maybe a little help from the [harmony-reflect](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect) shim.

There's a really good example on the Mozilla Developer Network on using a Proxy to [find an array item object by it's property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Finding_an_array_item_object_by_its_property) which pretty much sums it up.

Here's my version:

```
  var players = new Proxy(
  [{
    name: 'monkey',
    score: 50
  }, {
    name: 'giraffe',
    score: 100
  }, {
    name: 'pelican',
    score: 150
  }], {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
      if (prop in obj) {
        // default behavior
        return obj[prop];
      }
      if (typeof prop == 'string') {

        if (prop == 'rank') {
          return obj.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.score > b.score ? -1 : 1;
          });
        }

        if (prop == 'revrank') {
          return obj.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.score < b.score ? -1 : 1;
          });
        }

        var winner;
        var score = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          var player = obj[i];
          if (player.name == prop) {
            return player;
          } else if (player.score > score) {
            score = player.score;
            winner = player;
          }
        }

        if (prop == 'winner') {
          return winner;
        }
        return;
      }

    }
  });

  console.log(players[0]); // { name: 'monkey', score: 50 }
  console.log(players['monkey']); // { name: 'monkey', score: 50 }
  console.log(players['zebra']); // undefined
  console.log(players.rank); // [ { name: 'pelican', score: 150 },{ name: 'giraffe', score: 100 }, { name: 'monkey', score: 50 } ]
  console.log(players.revrank); // [ { name: 'monkey', score: 50 },{ name: 'giraffe', score: 100 },{ name: 'pelican', score: 150 } ]
  console.log(players.winner); // { name: 'pelican', score: 150 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest MDN documentation makes it quiet clear that Array index must be integers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```
let arr=[];
 arr[0]="zero";
 arr[1]="one";
 arr[2]="two";
 arr["fancy"]="what?";

//Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. 
//Setting non-integers using bracket notation will not set an element to the Array List itself
//A non-integer will set a variable associated with that ARRAY Object property collection 
let denseKeys = [...arr.keys()];
console.log(denseKeys);//[ 0, 1, 2 ]
console.log("ARRAY Keys:"+denseKeys.length);//3


let sparseKeys = Object.keys(arr);
console.log(sparseKeys);//[ '0', '1', '2', 'fancy' ]
console.log("Object Keys:"+sparseKeys.length);//4

const iterator = arr.keys();
for (const key of iterator) {
  console.log(key);//0,1,2
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

```
test = new Array();
test[0] = 'yellow';
test['banana'] = 0;
alert(test[test['banana']]);
```