# Abbreviation for PHP's array()

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, performance, syntactic-sugar

I don't know how about you, but I'm not very fond of the way arrays are constructed in PHP. I have this feeling that I use `array` keyword way too often and that `array($k => $v)` or e.g. `array($k1=>array($k2=>$v))` are way too long given usefulness of maps.
(Moreover, recently I've learned [JS way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076658/javascript-array-associative-and-indexed) and now I really am jealous)

The best I could come up with to remedy this is:

```
function a() { // array
  return func_get_args();
}
```

and

```
function h() { // hash
  $array=array();
  for($i=0; $i<func_num_args()-1; $i+=2) {
    $array[func_get_arg($i)]=func_get_arg($i+1);
  }
  return $array;
}
```

...but they don't permit using `=>` operator.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Arrays in PHP have never really felt like arrays to me. An array to me is a strictly one-dimensional keyless list of elements. Oh well..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php), a [shorthand syntax for arrays](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is supported using `[` and `]`. Your examples:

```
array($k => $v)
array($k1=>array($k2=>$v))
```

can now be written as:

```
[$k => $v]
[$k1 => [$k2 => $v]]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no shorthand syntax for declaring arrays in PHP. It's a feature I would like to see, but I very much doubt it will happen.

It's been discussed a lot by the PHP developers and the PHP community, but it was never implemented. A good starting point if you want to see how the discussion unfolded is available on the PHP wiki: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays

For now, you will have to put up with typing a handful of extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use Texter or any decent editor with templates/macros. E.g.:

```
[]+Tab ---> array({cursor})
```

If you're truly obsessed, make a json_decode macro to run a selection through this:

```
<?php var_export(json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN), true));
```

Just don't put JSON in your PHP code because you'd rather look at JSON...