# Can a javascript array be both numerical and associative?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript array associative AND indexed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076658/javascript-array-associative-and-indexed)

I am returning an array from a function and am wondering if I can have both a string association and numerical associations as well.

Ex:

```
array[0] = green;
array[1] = blue;
array['what'] = colors;
```

Comment: The best way to learn is to try, so try it.

Comment: you're right. should i delete this question?

Comment: I just quickly plugged this into my JavaScript Console. The entry for `what` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @wecsam, http://jsfiddle.net/YuaEn/

Comment: @wecsam: It works if you access it by its property name: `array.what`. It'll be ignored by Array methods.

Comment: Oh, I see. I simply typed in `array` to see the values, and the console returned `["green", "blue"]`.

Answer (score 0):

In some way yes, because it's some type of Object. But it's wrong use of them :)
Use objects (`{}`) for named (stringish) indexes and arrays(`[]`) for number indexes.

Comment: There are some uses for this. Sometimes you just want to carry along some additional data on the Array object.

Comment: In some special uses of course, you can mix them, but it can confuse other user of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are just objects with a special length property and some handy inhertited methods. Since arrays are objects, their property names are strings however the numeric ones ('0','1','2', etc.) are visited by array methods whereas non–numeric ones (e.g. length) aren't. Also, many array methods are generic and can be applied to any object with suitable properties (i.e. a numeric length property and some numeric property names).

Note that to be considered an index, the property name must satisfy the [rules for index names](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4) so:

```
var x = [];
x['00'] = '00';  // length = zero as '00' is not an index
x['0']  = '0';   // length = 1 as '0' is an index
```

It's generally considered bad form to use an array where a plain object will do, though there are no consequences for doing so other than if you mess with the *length* property.