# LRU cache implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, caching, lru

Java has LinkedHashMap which [gets you 99% there to an LRU cache](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/09/23/linkedhashmap-trick/).

Is there a Javascript implementation of an LRU cache, preferably from a reputable source, that is:

1. understandable
2. efficient (amortized O(1) get/put/delete)

? I've been searching on the web but couldn't find one; I thought I found one on [Ajax Design Patterns](http://web.archive.org/web/20150902003300/http://ajaxpatterns.org:80/Browser-Side_Cache) but it glosses over the `sendToTail()` method and has O(n) performance (presumably, since the queue and associative array are split up).

I suppose I could write my own, but I've learned the hard way that reinventing the wheel for core algorithms can be hazardous to one's health :/

Comment: Using a circular buffer and Map object, this is garbage-collection-friendly and asynchronous on cache-misses: https://github.com/tugrul512bit/LruJS/blob/main/lrucache.js (it is CLOCK-2-hand version of LRU). Has only 1 star so its better than zero star reputation :)

Answer (score 75):

[Map should be O(1) in most implementations average case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation). Since Map keeps insertion order, adding a bit of code around it will get you a LRU and for most uses this should be plenty fast.

I needed a simple LRU cache for a small number of expensive operations (1 second). I felt better about copy-pasting some small code rather than introducing something external, but since I didn't find it I wrote it:

```
class LRU {
    constructor(max = 10) {
        this.max = max;
        this.cache = new Map();
    }

    get(key) {
        let item = this.cache.get(key);
        if (item !== undefined) {
            // refresh key
            this.cache.delete(key);
            this.cache.set(key, item);
        }
        return item;
    }

    set(key, val) {
        // refresh key
        if (this.cache.has(key)) this.cache.delete(key);
        // evict oldest
        else if (this.cache.size === this.max) this.cache.delete(this.first());
        this.cache.set(key, val);
    }

    first() {
        return this.cache.keys().next().value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
> let cache = new LRU(3)
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(v => cache.set(v, 'v:'+v))
> cache.get(2)
undefined
> cache.get(3)
"v:3"
> cache.set(6, 6)
> cache.get(4)
undefined
> cache.get(3)
"v:3"
```

Comment: how is your this.first() working? Map doesn't provide `first()`

Comment: @TaranGoel The `.first()` is implemented right there in the code. Just see below the `set()`.

Comment: Awesome @odinho-Velmont, seems like Map possesses many capabilities already to help us implementing LRU cache. I was trying with simple JS Object (as Hash Table) and DoublyLinkedList and it's becoming quite cumbersome.

Comment: this fails the leetcode LRU problem. see: https://gist.github.com/Vandivier/ea2228f8f363417aa6392612e5399449

Comment: @JohnVandivier Why? I registered on that site and used your example, it says "Accepted" for me with runtime 95ms and all test cases passing.

Comment: ah well I can't say much other than it doesn't work for me, so I guess we see different results. I posted a screenshot in the gist above

Comment: @odinho-Velmont John's answer works. I assume he's referring to the solution from the top of the thread where `get` returns `undefined` instead of `-1` as expected by the test suite on LC.

Comment: @StevenTsao Yeah, People need to adjust it to what they need of course. :) Like returning `-1` if not found if that's what they require (like leetcode). Sure the code won't work directly 1-to-1 copied into tests that require slightly different API :P

Comment: I updated this to handle falsy items like `''` and `0` better. The code base I was adding this to has a strict rule on not doing un-needed stuff like checking for undefined unless you know there will be other falsy value there.   However, this is a nice example to copy-paste anywhere for anything so now it is more generally useful and will handle `0` and `''` as real values.

Answer (score 9):

This:

https://github.com/monsur/jscache

seems to fit you case although `setItem` (i.e. put) is O(N) in the worst case, that happens if the cache is filled up on insertion. In this case the cache is searched to purge expired items or least recently used items. `getItem` is O(1) and the expiry is handled on the `getItem` operation (i.e. if the item being fetched is expired, removes it and returns null).

The code is compact enough to be easily understood.

P.S. It might be useful to add to the constructor the option to specify the `fillFactor`, which is fixed to 0.75 (meaning that when the cache is purged it's size is reduced at least to 3/4th of the maximum size)

Comment: thanks, I did run across that. It seemed like it had too many bells & whistles for my application (not to mention the phrase ASP.NET which is a huge red flag in my mind), but maybe I should give it another look.

Comment: +1 The implementation has nothing to do with ASP.NET I think it is worth a look

Answer (score 7):

This is worth a mention:
https://github.com/rsms/js-lru

The core set of functions are O(1) and the code is heavily commented (with ASCII art too!)

Answer (score 4):

The monsur.com implementation is O(n) on insertion only because it has items which actually expire on real world time. It is not a simple LRU. If you only care about maintaining the most recently used items without regard to real world time, this can be done in O(1). A queue, implemented as a doubly linked list, is O(1) for insertion or deletion from the end, and this is all you should need for a cache. As for lookup, a hash map, which javascript makes pathetically easy, should be good for nearly O(1) lookup (assuming the javascript engine uses a good hashmap, that's implementation dependent of course). So you have a linked list of items with a hash map pointing to the items. Manipulate the ends of the linked list as needed to put new items and requested items on one end and remove old items from the other end.

Comment: the linked list needs to be able to delete (but not insert) items from the middle if items are removed from the LRU cache and reinserted. That's the hard part, your answer seems to gloss over that.

Comment: Redundantly, removing from the middle of a doubly linked list is O(n), which you would have to do to maintain the LRU invariant on access.

Comment: @Eloff, There is the additional hash map to get to any element anywhere in the list with O(1). But you and "Jason S" are right that manipulating the ends isn't enough, _any_ item at any position in the list can be the next one that needs to go back to the front position, so while insertion is at one end removal can be from any position. Still, thanks to the hash map that can be done independent of the length of the list.

Answer (score 2):

This library [runtime-memcache](https://github.com/tusharf5/runtime-memcache) implements lru and a few other caching schemes in javascript.

It uses modified Doubly Linked List to achieve O(1) for `get`, `set` and `remove`. You can check out the implementation which is pretty simple.

Comment: interesting... could you comment on any testing / peer review that would help someone justify use of this library? (My question was from 2009 and I have no idea what I was doing at the time, but maybe your answer can help someone else)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an LRU cache, but I've got [my own linked map implementation](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/map.js). As it uses a JS objects as store, it'll have similar performance characteristics (the wrapper objects and hash function impart a performance penalty).

Currently, documentation is [basically non-existant](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks-docs/raw-file/tip/map-api-en.html), but there's a [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent/383540#383540).

The `each()` method will pass the current key, the current value and a boolean indicating if there are more elements as arguments to the callback function.

Alternatively, looping can be done manually via

```
for(var i = map.size; i--; map.next()) {
    var currentKey = map.key();
    var currentValue = map.value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is an old question but adding a link for future refrence.
Check out https://github.com/monmohan/dsjslib . This has a LRU Cache implementation in addition to some other data structures. Such caches (and this one too) maintain doubly linked list of cache entries in LRU order i.e. entries move to the head as they are accessed and are removed from tail when they are reclaimed (say by expiry or because size limit was reached). Its O(1) since it only involves constant number of pointer manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

I improve @odinho's answer to fit [this leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/)

change `if (item)` to `if (item != undefined)` to fit value === 0 case

following is my code:

```
class LRUCache {
  constructor(max = 10) {
    this.max = max
    this.cache = new Map()
  }

  get(key) {
    let item = this.cache.get(key)
    if (item !== undefined) {
      // refresh key
      this.cache.delete(key)
      this.cache.set(key, item)
    }
    return item === undefined ? -1 : item
  }

  put(key, val) {
    // refresh key
    if (this.cache.has(key)) this.cache.delete(key)
    // evict oldest
    else if (this.cache.size == this.max) this.cache.delete(this.first())
    this.cache.set(key, val)
  }

  first() {
    return this.cache.keys().next().value
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since we need read, write, update and delete operations in O(1), we use two data structures.

1. An Object(or Map)in JavaScript provides retrieval in O(1).
2. A Doubly LinkedList(Custom data structure we create) makes below functionalities in O(1)

   - change position of the most used element to the top
   - delete least used element from cache on reaching cache limit.

The custom implementation of *Doubly LinkedList* and *Least Recently Used* cache with clear explanation is given below.

https://medium.com/dsinjs/implementing-lru-cache-in-javascript-94ba6755cda9

Comment: Don't link to an external resource, inline your implementation in the answer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this implementation will fail with multiple put/write to the same key -- every element in the cache will be for the same key, which is NOT how LRU should work

Answer (score -2):

External package/library is not required, we can write our own code to implement LRU in javascript, Please refer https://dev.to/udayvunnam/implementing-lru-cache-in-javascript-3c8g site for details.

Comment: Please explain your answer with some additional information, not only with link to outer source.

Comment: This is the same answer as [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56296618/675721). The other answer was posted a year earlier by the original author