# Are JavaScript Map Objects Indexed to Optimize map.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, collections, ecmascript-6

Behind the scenes, in V8, are JavaScript-Map-object's keys indexed in some manner that optimizes the `map.get` method? Or does `map.get()` simply just loop through the entire map until it discovers a key match?

I'm interested in the efficiency of `map.get` on larger mappings of 500,000+ key/value pairs. I have this many mappings that I'd like to just cache in RAM, instead of querying a database where the keys are already indexed for fast value-retrieval. It seems to me, that querying RAM instead of a database would be faster if the Map object's keys are somehow indexed behind the scenes.

Abstract:

```
function randomUniqueThing()
{
   // returns (magically) a unique random: 
   //  string, number, function, array or object.
}
var objMap = new Map();
var count = 0;
var thing1,thing2;
while(count < 500000)
{
    thing1 = randomUniqueThing();
    thing2 = randomUniqueThing();
    objMap.set(thing1, thing2);
    count++;
}
var lastValue = objMap.get(thing1); // Will getting this last
                                    // thing's value take longer
                                    // than getting other values?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as you would expect from such a data type, a `Map` does utilize a hash-table under the hood.

### Proof by source:

As always, the proof is in the source:

#### Excerpt from V8 source file [`src/objects.h`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/01590d660d6c8602b616a82816c4aea2a251be63/src/objects.h#L9582-L9596) `class JSMap`:

```
// The JSMap describes EcmaScript Harmony maps
class JSMap : public JSCollection {
 public:
  DECLARE_CAST(JSMap)

  static void Initialize(Handle<JSMap> map, Isolate* isolate);
  static void Clear(Handle<JSMap> map);

  // Dispatched behavior.
  DECLARE_PRINTER(JSMap)
  DECLARE_VERIFIER(JSMap)

 private:
  DISALLOW_IMPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS(JSMap);
};
```

As we can see, `JSMap` extends `JSCollection`.

Now if we take a look at the declaration for `JSCollection`:

#### Excerpt from V8 source file [`src/objects.h`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/01590d660d6c8602b616a82816c4aea2a251be63/src/objects.h#L9552-L9562) `class JSCollection`:

```
class JSCollection : public JSObject {
 public:
  // [table]: the backing hash table
  DECL_ACCESSORS(table, Object)

  static const int kTableOffset = JSObject::kHeaderSize;
  static const int kSize = kTableOffset + kPointerSize;

 private:
  DISALLOW_IMPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS(JSCollection);
};
```

Here we can see that it uses a hash table, with a nice comment to clarify it.

---

There was some question as to if that hash table refers only to object properties, and not to the `get` method. As we can from the source code to `Map.prototype.get`, a hash map is being used.

#### Excerpt from V8 source file [`src/js/collection.js`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/collection.js#L306-L318) `MapGet`:

```
function MapGet(key) {
  if (!IS_MAP(this)) {
    throw MakeTypeError(kIncompatibleMethodReceiver,
                        'Map.prototype.get', this);
  }
  var table = %_JSCollectionGetTable(this);
  var numBuckets = ORDERED_HASH_TABLE_BUCKET_COUNT(table);
  var hash = GetExistingHash(key);
  if (IS_UNDEFINED(hash)) return UNDEFINED;
  var entry = MapFindEntry(table, numBuckets, key, hash);
  if (entry === NOT_FOUND) return UNDEFINED;
  return ORDERED_HASH_MAP_VALUE_AT(table, entry, numBuckets);
}
```

#### Excerpt from V8 source file [`src/js/collection.js`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/collection.js#L61-L77) `MapFindEntry`:

```
function MapFindEntry(table, numBuckets, key, hash) {
  var entry = HashToEntry(table, hash, numBuckets);
  if (entry === NOT_FOUND) return entry;
  var candidate = ORDERED_HASH_MAP_KEY_AT(table, entry, numBuckets);
  if (key === candidate) return entry;
  var keyIsNaN = NumberIsNaN(key);
  while (true) {
    if (keyIsNaN && NumberIsNaN(candidate)) {
      return entry;
    }
    entry = ORDERED_HASH_MAP_CHAIN_AT(table, entry, numBuckets);
    if (entry === NOT_FOUND) return entry;
    candidate = ORDERED_HASH_MAP_KEY_AT(table, entry, numBuckets);
    if (key === candidate) return entry;
  }
  return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

### Proof by benchmarking:

There is another way to test if it uses a hash map. Make many entries, and test what the longest and shortest lookup times are. Something like this:

```
'use strict';

let m = new Map();
let a = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    let o = {};
    m.set(o, i);
    a.push(o);
}

let lookupLongest = null;
let lookupShortest = null;

a.forEach(function(item) {
    let dummy;
    let before = Date.now();
    dummy = m.get(item);
    let after = Date.now();
    let diff = after - before;
    if (diff > lookupLongest || lookupLongest === null) {
        lookupLongest = diff;
    }
    if (diff < lookupShortest || lookupShortest === null) {
        lookupShortest = diff;
    }
});
console.log('Longest Lookup Time:', lookupLongest);
console.log('Shortest Lookup Time:', lookupShortest);
```

After a few seconds, I get the following output:

```
$ node test.js
Longest Lookup Time: 1
Shortest Lookup Time: 0
```

Such close lookup times would certainly not be possible if it where looping though every entry.

Comment: Because of this, would you expect map.get to be faster than querying an indexed database-table for any of these same 500,000 key-values?

Comment: @LonnieBest I would definitely expect that to the case, since they would already be available in memory. It might be possible that the database has a faster lookup, depending on the data, but I imagine the latency would outweigh this. When in doubt, benchmark it!

Comment: Without the index/hash (behind the scenes) would you still expect RAM to be faster than querying an indexed database-table? Indexed-keys in databases return values super fast even in very large datasets. I see your edit...

Comment: @LonnieBest Not if the data was very large. Speed when querying large data sets comes from binary searching and/or hash tables. If you had to loop over an unsorted array of thousands of results, it could easily take longer than a binary search in a database of indexed data.

Comment: "*In fact, Map is a subclass of Object.*" - of course it is, as all map objects are objects. But this only does seem to suggest that using properties (with `.` or `[]`) on a Map is implemented using a hashmap. What about `.get()` and `.set()`? Forgive me if the C++ code says more about that.

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough. See my updated answer for more on the `get` implementation.

Comment: @Bergi : This question may have been asked before, but Alexander's answer here is excellent (perhaps canonical).