# Find the two numbers that will equal the desired sum

Tags: javascript

I had a technical interview and one of the questions was to find the two numbers in the array that would equal the desired sum. For the life of me, I can not find the solution.

```js
var input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
var dSum = 28; // return would be [12,16]
```

Comment: @amrendersingh it's not sorted as you can see from the posted code

Comment: Something is very wrong with how people answering this question is behaving.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I was just think that.

Comment: What solutions did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please have a look at this simple code** because I'm pretty sure this is what you need:

```js
function detectPair(sum, array) {
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) continue;
      else if (array[i] + array[j] === sum) return [array[i], array[j]];
    }
  }; return null;
}


let sum = 28;
let array = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5]

console.log(detectPair(sum, array)); //return would be [12,16]
```

---

**Edit @uom-pgregorio**: '`There wasn't any constraints that the same number can't be used. So a 14 + 14 in this case should still be accepted`'

*I'm pretty sure you've mixed something up*: The line `if (i == j) continue;` is not preventing the situation that `14+14` is correct, it is preventing that if the array just includes a number `(like 14)` it uses the same number a several times.

```
==> `i == j` is checking the indexes not the values
```

**Maybe just try this setup**:

```
let sum = 28;
let array = [3, 5, 7, 14, 14] // includes 14 two times
```

Comment: There wasn't any constraints that the same number can't be used. So a `14 + 14` in this case should still be accepted.

Comment: @Casdams Sure, no problem. I hope my answer helps you. `:)`

Comment: First correct answer. Should be marked as "correct" IMO

Comment: @Cadams: really?

Answer (score 8):

Use a `Set()`, for solving this problem in `O(n)`. The approach is simple :

- Take an empty set. And for each element e in `input` check:

  (a)  If the set contains `sum - e` . if yes then print the pair `(e, sum -e)` .

  (b)    Insert e into set.

  Try the following:

```js
let input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
let dSum = 28;
let set = new Set();

for(item of input) {
  let num = dSum - item;
  if(set.has(num)) {
    console.log(num + " " + item);
    break;
  }
  set.add(item);
}
```

Comment: Best answer! But I can not understand why you checking `i > 0`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Thanks for pointing out, it was redundant. Updated the answer :-)

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This is not O(n), `set.has` has O(logn) complexity, which makes this `nlogn`.

Comment: @Helpinghand set provides a O(1) insert and lookup. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation

Answer (score 2):

```js
function findSumPair(input, target) {
   for(let a = 0; a < input.length; a++) {
      for(let b = a; b < input.length; b++) {
         if(input[a]+input[b] === target)
            return [input[a], input[b]];
      }
   }
}
console.log(findSumPair([3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5], 28));
```

The inner loop can be started at the current index of the outer loop (rather than 0) because the previous combinations have already been checked.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
var dSum = 28; // return would be [12,16]

let el1 = Math.max(...input)
let el2 = Math.max(...input.filter(i => i !== el1))

console.log([el1, el2])
```

Or

```js
let input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
let dSum = 28; // return would be [12,16]
let result

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  for (let k = i; k < input.length; k++)
    if (i !== k && input[i] + input[k] === dSum)
      result = [input[i], input[k]]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the double nested solutions and solutions with more than one loop, you could use a single loop approach with a hash table for the still missing number and a short circuit if this number is found in the array.

This approach is a fast one, because it uses a `for` loop with an object as storage for a fast access, and a variable `value` for `array[i]`.

Big O is in worst case O(n).

```js
function getPair(array, sum) {
    var i, l,
        hash = Object.create(null),
        value;
        
    for (i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        value = array[i];
        if (hash[value]) {
            return [sum - value, value];
        }
        hash[sum - value] = true;
    }
}

console.log(getPair([3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5], 28));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this works, but the algorithm is really bad, O(n^2) I think.

```
for (i of input) {
    for (j of input) {
        if (i + j == dSum)
            console.log([i, j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findPair(input, sum) {
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for(let j = i; j < input.length; j++) {
      if(input[i] + input[j] == sum) return [input[i], input[j]];
    }
  }
  return [];
}

console.log(findPair([3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5], 28));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; J < input.length; j++)
        if (input[i]+input[j] == dSum)
            console.log([input[i], input[j]])
```

Edit:
I thought there was a constraint of i<>j. I removed that constraint

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
var dSum = 28;
twoSum(input, dSum);
function twoSum (arr, target) {
  let results = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] === target - arr[i]) {
        results.push([arr[i], arr[j]])
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@amrender-singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6514231/amrender-singh) Has the best answer here.

To honour him, here's a snippet using his code to find the first *or all sums* with a certain value in an `Array`

```js
const log = (...strs) => 
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent += `${strs.join(" ")}\n`;
const array = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];

log("All possible sums 28 in array:", findSumsInArray(array, 28));
log("First sum 28 in array:", findSumsInArray(array, 28, true));
log("All possible sums 22 in array:", findSumsInArray(array, 22));
log("First sum 22 in array:", findSumsInArray(array, 22, true));
log("All possible sums 12 in array:", findSumsInArray(array, 12));
log("First sum 12 in array:", findSumsInArray(array, 12, true));
log("First sum 28 in array [3, 5, 7, 14, 14]:", 
     findSumsInArray([3, 5, 7, 14, 14], 28, true));

function findSumsInArray(array, sum2Find, firstOnly) {
  let set = new Set(array);
  let result = [];
  const errorStr = `Sum ${sum2Find} not possible in [${array}]`;
  for (let item of array) {
    let num = sum2Find - item;
    if (set.has(num)) {
      const report = `${num}+${item}`;
      if (firstOnly) {
        return report;
      }
      result.push(report);
      set.delete(item);
   }
  }
  return result.length ? `[${result.join(", ")}]` : errorStr;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late in contributing, but no one appears to have posted the obligatory JavaScript one-liner.

```
let input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
let dSum = 28;
let Result = [];

input.forEach( i=>{ input.forEach( j=>{ i+j==dSum && Result.push([i,j]); }); });
```

The `Result` array will contain the solutions, of which there are two in this case:

`[[12, 16], [16, 12]]`

Generalising this to a function where values representing `input` and `dSum` are user-defined parameters:

```
pairsFromArrayWithSum = (total, Numbers) 
                      => Numbers.forEach(a => { 
                         Numbers.forEach(b => { 
                         a + b == total && Result.push([a,b]);
                         }); });
```

Then, given:

```
Result = [];
pairsFromArrayWithSum(50, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]);
```

the `Result` array will contain:

```
[ [ 3, 47 ],
  [ 7, 43 ],
  [ 13, 37 ],
  [ 19, 31 ],
  [ 31, 19 ],
  [ 37, 13 ],
  [ 43, 7 ],
  [ 47, 3 ] ]
```

Comment: Maybe improve this so that you don't get the same combination in a different order? `12 + 16` really is talking about the same array elements `16 + 12` and only one of them is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5];
let dSum = 28;
let set = new Set();

for(item of input) {
  let num = dSum - item;
  if(set.has(num)) {
    console.log(num + " " + item);
    break;
  }
  set.add(item);
}
```

```js
function detectPair(sum, array) {
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) continue;
      else if (array[i] + array[j] === sum) return [array[i], array[j]];
    }
  }; return null;
}


let sum = 28;
let array = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5]

console.log(detectPair(sum, array)); //return would be [12,16]
```

```js
function detectPair(sum, array) {
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) continue;
      else if (array[i] + array[j] === sum) return [array[i], array[j]];
    }
  }; return null;
}


let sum = 28;
let array = [3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 12, 4, 9, 16, 5]

console.log(detectPair(sum, array)); //return would be [12,16]
```

Comment: Supporting comments from your side would be more than welcome, in order to help others understand faster your idea behind the code :) Thanks!