# How can i implement functional loop statements instead of for loops in this case?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, functional-programming

How to check if sum of any two elements in the array exists in the array using functional loop statements(map, forEach, reduce) instead of for loops.

For example an array like this

```
[1, 2, 9, 4, 3] // would return true as 1 + 2 = 3
[2,7,12,6,8,20]  // true as 2 + 6 = 8 which is enough to make it true
[1, 2, 4, 9] //would return false
```

I can do this by for loops:

```
const checkSumExist = arr => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(arr.includes(arr[i] + arr[j])) return true;   
    }
  }

  return false; 
}
```

So is there a solution using functional loop statement instead of nested for loops in this case???

Comment: I think your solution is incorrect because you're only checking for exactly 2 elements and not "sum of at least two elements".

Comment: @slider it is correct, if sum of any two elements in array exists in array, true should be returned, just two elements not 3 or 4

Comment: In that case you should edit your description to "any two" and not "at least 2".

Comment: @slider done!! thanks

Answer (score 6):

A simplified implementation –

```js
const main = (xs = []) =>
  xs .some ((n, i) =>
    xs .some ((m, j) =>
      i < j && xs .includes (n + m)
    )
  )
  
console.log
  ( main ([ 1, 2, 4, 9, 4, 3 ])   // true
  , main ([ 2, 7, 12, 6, 8, 20 ]) // true
  , main ([ 1, 2, 4, 9 ])         // false
  )
```

This optimization using `Set` [improves speed to `O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation) –

```js
const main = (xs = [], s = new Set (xs)) =>
  xs .some ((n, i) =>
    xs .some ((m, j) =>
      i < j && s .has (n + m)
    )
  )

console.log
  ( main ([ 1, 2, 4, 9, 4, 3 ])   // true
  , main ([ 2, 7, 12, 6, 8, 20 ]) // true
  , main ([ 1, 2, 4, 9 ])         // false
  )
```

Remember only to optimize where necessary

Comment: Ah I totally forgot that `.some` gives you the index as the 2nd parameter! Nice

Comment: Also if you're on V8 it looks like the Set lookup should also be O(1) based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Neat to see Set optimized in this way!

Comment: @user633183 Nice solution! Tiny performance improvement: replace `i !== j` with `i < j`.

Comment: Tex, thanks for the comment. Does that really count as a performance improvement? `i` will always be less than (or equal to `j`), so I think `!==` is the absolute minimum required operation to compute the correct answer.  All things else aside, is `<` faster than `!==`?

Comment: @user633183 `s .has (n + m)` will often be evaluated fewer times if you substitute `!==` with `<`. Using your second code example, `s .has (n + m)` is evaluated 16 times. After replacing `!==` with `<`, it is only evaluated 10 times. `i` will not always be less than or equal to `j`.

Comment: Tex, I see it now. This is actually a non-trivial optimization, especially for large `xs`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Edit--I forgot that `.some` provides the index of each element as the 2nd parameter. This makes it a bit cleaner!

```js
const foo = [1, 2, 9, 4, 3]; // would return true
const bar = [1, 2, 4, 9]; // would return false
const baz = [2,7,12,6,8,20]; // should also be true

const sumOf2Exists = (arr) => {
  // create a hash of the values in arr so we can check the
  // accept condition in O(1) time
  const hash = arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
    acc[n] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  // find some n, m where n and m aren't the same entry 
  // and the sum n+m is in arr (using the hash)
  return arr.some((n, i) => arr.some((m, j) => j > i && hash[n + m]));
};

console.log(sumOf2Exists(foo))
console.log(sumOf2Exists(bar))
console.log(sumOf2Exists(baz));
```

Inspired by comment from tex and using Immutable.js

```js
const { Set, Range } = Immutable

const foo = [1, 2, 9, 4, 3]; // would return true
const bar = [1, 2, 4, 9]; // would return false
const baz = [2, 7, 12, 6, 8, 20]; // should also be true

const sumOf2Exists = (arr) => {
  const hash = Set(arr);
  return arr.some((n, i) => (
    Range(i+1, arr.length).some(j => hash.has(n + arr[j]))
  ));
};

console.log(sumOf2Exists(foo))
console.log(sumOf2Exists(bar))
console.log(sumOf2Exists(baz));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i think so, for loops is much clear and readable in this case!!

Comment: There may be more concise solution, but at least I vote +1, because you use `reduce`. I think this sort of problem to loop same kind in list without `reduce` is out of problem.

Comment: I'd argue `.some` is also a special case of reduce, except nicer because it short-circuits.

Comment: @Pysul also good stuff, especially the second example (due to its brevity) for anyone not using `Set`. Yours would also perform slightly better in some cases if you replace `!==` with `<` (using `&&` as a control flow operator, you'd skip some more evaluations of `hash[n + m]` given some inputs and substituting `<` for `!==`). Minor, but it will make your functional solution closer in terms of efficiency to the imperative example in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The idea in the following solution is to use `reduce` and `map` to build all possible combinations of 2 numbers and then use `some` to test if sum of any combination is in the array.

```js
function sumExists(arr) {
  return arr
    .reduce((acc, curr, i) => acc.concat(arr.slice(i + 1).map(e => [curr, e])), [])
    .some(([a, b]) => arr.includes(a + b));
}

console.log(sumExists([1, 2, 9, 4, 3]));
console.log(sumExists([2, 7, 12, 6, 8, 20]));
console.log(sumExists([1, 2, 4, 9]));
```

An *O(n^2)* version would be the following:

```js
function sumExists(arr) {
  const sums = new Set(arr);
  return arr
    .reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
      acc.push(...arr.slice(i + 1).map(e => [curr, e]));
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .some(([a, b]) => sums.has(a + b));
}

console.log(sumExists([1, 2, 9, 4, 3]));
console.log(sumExists([2, 7, 12, 6, 8, 20]));
console.log(sumExists([1, 2, 4, 9]));
```

Comment: this would be much slower!!, but smart anyway

Comment: @SaherElgendy you're right. You can make it faster by changing the `includes` check to `has` in a set and to avoid using `concat` as that creates a completely new array. So time complexity wise, the set version is now better than the `for` loop version (which is *O(n^3)* because of `includes`).

Comment: This has worse space complexity than the for loop version though

Comment: @Pysul I agree.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using Rxjs:

```
import { Observable, from, of, zip, pairs, combineLatest, empty } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, takeUntil, takeWhile, single, zipAll, pairwise, combineAll, mergeMap, merge, first, skip, skipWhile, defaultIfEmpty } from 'rxjs/operators';

let test1 = [1, 2, 9, 4, 3]; // would return true as 1 + 2 = 3
let test2 = [2,7,12,6,8,20];  // true as 2 + 6 = 8 which is enough to make it true
let test3 = [1, 2, 4, 9]; //would return false


let observable1 = from(test1);

let skipSameIndex = (arr:number[], anchorIndex:number) => {
    return from(arr).pipe(
        filter((v, i) => {
        // console.log('anchodIndex:', anchorIndex, ', i:', i);
        return anchorIndex !== i;
        })
    )
}

let pairAll = (arr:number[]) => from(arr).pipe(mergeMap( (x, index) => {
    return combineLatest(of(x), skipSameIndex(arr, index))
}));

let isPairExistsInArray = (pair:[number, number], arr: number[]) => {
    let isExists = arr.indexOf(pair[0] + pair[1]) >= 0; 

    // console.log('pair:', pair, ', isExists:', isExists);

    return isExists;
}


let isSumEachElementsExists = (arr:number[]) => pairAll(arr).pipe(    
    map((pair:[number, number]) => isPairExistsInArray(pair, arr)),    
    // first(isExists => isExists)
    filter(x => x),
    defaultIfEmpty(false)
);

// skipSameIndex(test3, 1).subscribe(x => console.log(x));


isSumEachElementsExists(test1).toPromise()
    .then(isExists => console.log('test1 isExists:', isExists))
    .catch(err => console.log('ERROR:', err));


isSumEachElementsExists(test2).toPromise()
    .then(isExists => console.log('test2 isExists:', isExists))
    .catch(err => console.log('ERROR:', err));

isSumEachElementsExists(test3).toPromise()
    .then(isExists => console.log('test3 isExists:', isExists))
    .catch(err => console.log('ERROR:', err));
```

My conclusion after this is FP is hard and the solution is overly complex compare to iterative programming :). I am open for suggestion or correction if anyone can simplify this.

Comment: Actually this was the aim of my question, i hate for loops and all my other solutions was far complex so i asked if someone has more neat and simpler solution but seems that for loop may be the best solution in some situations!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct solution because I don't quite understand what you mean by functional loop but check this out, this solution is without any loops.

```
function check(list, i, j) {
    if(i >= list.length || j >= list.length) return false;
    if(i != j && list.includes(list[i] + list[j])) return true;
    return check(list, i+1, j) || check(list, i, j+1)
}

check([1,2,9,4,3], 0, 0)
true

check([1,2, 4, 9], 0, 0)
false
```

Comment: functional loop statement map, forEach, reduce..you are doing a recursion right now!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this a brute force and over-engineered solution, but I challenged myself to provide a vanilla JS, purely-functional approach to solve the problem.

BTW, there're libraries out there like [Sanctuary](https://sanctuary.js.org/) or [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/), or many others, which would save the boilerplate part of my answer.

It has just an issue: it checks all summable combinations (`possibleSums`), but this is a plus, since one can print out all coincidences. Also, there's `someSumExists` which just checks that `possibleSums` outputs one or more coincidences.

In the other hand, it has another issue: it relies on the fact that inputs won't contain repeated numbers.

```js
// ::: Combinators :::

// I :: a -> a -> a
const I = x => x

// T :: a -> (a -> a) -> a
const T = x => f => f (x)

// W :: a -> (a -> a -> a) -> a
const W = x => f => f (x) (x)

// ::: Non-generalized, partial Functor, Chain, Applicative Array-specific instances... :::

// map :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
const map = f => xs => xs.map (f)

// chain :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
const chain = f => xs => xs.reduce((o, x) => [...o, ...f (x)], [])

// ap :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
const ap = ms => m => chain (x => map (f => f(x)) (ms)) (m)

// lift2 :: [a -> c -> d] -> [a -> b] -> [b -> c] -> [d]
const lift2 = f => xs => ys => ap (map (f) (xs)) (ys)

// join :: [[a]] -> [a]
const join = chain (I)

// ::: Utils :::

// pipe :: [Any -> Any] -> Any -> Any
const pipe = xs => x => xs.reduce ((x, f) => f (x), x)

// any :: (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> Boolean
const any = f => xs => xs.some (f)

// joinWith :: String -> [Any] -> [String]
const joinWith = sep => xs => xs.join (sep)

// length :: [Any] -> Number
const length = xs => xs.length

// equals :: a -> a -> Boolean
const equals = x => y => x === y

// not :: a -> Boolean
const not = x => x !== true

// possibleSums :: Number -> [[Number, Number, Number]]
const possibleSums = input =>
    pipe ([
       W,
       T (lift2 (x => y => x !== y && input.includes (x + y) ? [[x, y, x + y]] : [])),
       join
    ]) (input)
    
// someSumExists :: [Number] -> Boolean
const someSumExists = pipe ([ 
    possibleSums,
    length,
    equals (0),
    not
])

// printSums :: [[Number, Number, Number]] -> [String]
const printSums = pipe ([
    map (([x, y, r]) => `${x} + ${y} = ${r}`),
    joinWith ('\n')
])

// printPossibleSums :: [[Number, Number, Number]] -> String
const printPossibleSums = pipe ([ possibleSums, printSums ])
      
const input1 = [1, 2, 9, 4, 3] 
const input2 = [2,7,12,6,8,20] 
const input3 = [1, 2, 4, 9]

const output1 = printPossibleSums (input1)
const output1_ = someSumExists (input1)

const output2 = printPossibleSums (input2)
const output2_ = someSumExists (input2)

const output3 = printPossibleSums (input3)
const output3_ = someSumExists (input3)


console.log ('Input 1 has a case:', output1_)
console.log (output1)


console.log ('Input 2 has a case:', output2_)
console.log (output2)


console.log ('Input 3 has a case:', output3_)
console.log (output3)
```

## Less boilerplate: [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com)!

This the same approach using Ramda's functions to save some code lines:

```js
const { map, join, length, equals, not, pipe, lift, unnest } = R
const W = x => f => f (x) (x)
const T = x => f => f (x)

const possibleSums = input =>
    pipe (
       W,
       T (lift ((x, y) => x !== y && input.includes (x + y) ? [[x, y, x + y]] : [])),
       unnest
    ) (input)
    
const someSumExists = pipe ( 
    possibleSums,
    length,
    equals (0),
    not
)

const printSums = pipe (
    map (([x, y, r]) => `${x} + ${y} = ${r}`),
    join ('\n')
)

const printPossibleSums = pipe (possibleSums, printSums)

const input1 = [1, 2, 9, 4, 3] 
const input2 = [2,7,12,6,8,20] 
const input3 = [1, 2, 4, 9]

const output1 = printPossibleSums (input1)
const output1_ = someSumExists (input1)

const output2 = printPossibleSums (input2)
const output2_ = someSumExists (input2)

const output3 = printPossibleSums (input3)
const output3_ = someSumExists (input3)


console.log ('Input 1 has a case:', output1_)
console.log (output1)


console.log ('Input 2 has a case:', output2_)
console.log (output2)


console.log ('Input 3 has a case:', output3_)
console.log (output3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```