# Chaining "||" (or) vs JS.includes vs Switch for testing a set

Tags: javascript

When checking a short list of variables for being within a set, what structure is most efficient.

```
if(checkString === 'string1'
  || checkString === 'someString2'
  || checkString === 'differentString3'
  || checkString === 'lol'
  || checkString === 'jsIsFun'
){doThing();}
```

For readability I would prefer one of the following:

```
if(['string1', 'string2','differentString3', 'lol', 'jsIsFun'].includes(checkString)){
  doThing();
}
```

or:

```
switch (checkString) {
  case 'string1':
  case 'string2':
  case 'differentString3':
  case 'lol':
  case 'jsIsFun':
    doThing();
    break;
}
```

For a touch of background, I am trying to tidy chains of if-else with a similar structure to the first example. The `checkString` has a relatively even distribution of items it would expect to match in the set.

The structure of the data is not already in an array, so I am wondering if there is any meaningful memory cost to initializing an array for using 'includes'.

Is one of the above methods the most efficient for vanilla JS, or is there a better way to check for string belonging to a state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/whats-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values

Comment: "Best" is opinion based

Comment: i prefer something like `{string1:1, differentString3:1 ... }[checkString]` for non-repeatedness, speed, mashup-ability and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, there must be a difference in efficiency between the 3 options you listed (all done in linear time), and an object lookup (constant time) like you see below:

```
const checkObject = {
    'string1': true,
    'string2': true,
    'differentString3': true,
    'lol': true,
    'jsIsFun': true,
}

if (checkObject[checkString]) doThing()
```

or

```
const checkSet = new Set(['string1', 'string2', 'differentString3', 'lol', 'jsIsFun'])

if (checkSet.has(checkString)) doThing();
```

**if we do not count the time spent on initiating the checkObject and checkSet*

You can read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423914/performance-of-array-includes-vs-mapping-to-an-object-and-accessing-it-in-javasc), and check out this [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/myjyq4ixs1/2) comparison between an array includes, object, and set (the set is quite a bit faster than `array.includes`).

However, this won't make a significant difference for a small array, so it's really a matter of taste.