# If value does not exist in a Set or Hash Key, is it still O1 time?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given I have this real-world example

```
const whitelist = new Set(['192.0.2.1', '192.0.2.2','192.0.2.3']) //hard-coded ip list
const clientIP = request.headers.get("Client-IP");

if (await isSiteDown(request) && !whitelist.has(clientIP))
{
    return fetch('https://my-error-page.example.com');
}
return fetch(request)
```

I let's say user's ip is `192.0.2.4` and is not in the whitelist, would this still be in constant time search?

Comment: Yes, for the same reason the look-up is O(1) if it *is* present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It won't go through all the items and see if the string being searched for is one of the items - rather, it'll look up *only that string* to see if the Set contains it, which [will take constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33614512).

It's a bit like checking whether a property exists on an object (without messing with prototypes) - eg `obj.hasOwnProperty('bar')` doesn't iterate through all properties on the object to see if any match, it looks to see if *only* the `bar` property exists.

The same is true for Maps and their `.has` / `.get` methods.