# Big O for a loop vs a javasccript method that solves a problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Find if the two arrays contain a similar property or value.

```
const one =[1,2,3,4,5]
const two = [5,6,7,8]
```

```
// a double loop that solves this problem 
O(n^2)
```

VS

```
two.some(item => one.includes(item))
// this is more efficient than the double loop method 
// but behind the scenes isnt javascript just looping ?
// why is this more performant ? 
// and is the big O  of this O(n)?
```

Comment: "*this is more efficient than the double loop method*" - what makes you think that? You're right, it's still two nested loops, just written differently.

Comment: The second will have "short-circuiting", i.e., it will stop as soon as it finds a result. The first will as well if you implement it correctly. As for *"why is this more performant"* Big-O doesn't measure true performance in the way you appear to think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your

> a double loop that solves this problem

breaks out of the loops as soon as a match is found, then both methods are similarly inefficient - they both require iterating over all of N elements M times, worst-case, where N is the length of one array and M is the length of the other. (So, `O(n * m)`, or `O(n^2)`, depending on how you want to specify the lengths of the inputs.)

The advantage to the second method

```
two.some(item => one.includes(item))
```

is that it's a lot more *readable* than using `for` loops. It's not more performant - the opposite is true, `for` loops are generally faster than array methods.

If you wanted to reduce the complexity to `O(n)`, instead of iterating over the second array inside a loop, use a Set lookup inside the loop, which is much faster:

```
const oneSet = new Set(one);
return two.some(item => oneSet.has(item));
```

because [set lookup is sublinear, and generally O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33611509) - resulting in an overall complexity of `O(n)`.