# What is the time complexity of this code? lengthOfLongestSubstring

Tags: javascript, time, window, complexity-theory, sliding

Could you please help me with the time complexity of the code below?

This is a leet code problem - the function should take a string as input and return the length of the longest substring with non-repeating characters:

- input "abcabcbb" returns 3 as answer is 'abc'
- input "bbbbb" returns 1 as answer is 'b'
- input "pw**wke**w" returns 3 as answer is 'wke'

This can be solved with a sliding window technique which if implemented well is O(n). My initial solution shown below is sliding windowish, but my solution is not O(n) as there is an inner loop triggering sometimes and this inner loop is not required at all.

In short there is a nested loop, outer loop runs for every character of the input string. The inner loop will run every time a duplicate character is hit, and it will run as many times as the number of characters between the current character and the previous occurence of this character, so:

- input "abcabcbb", outer loop will execute 8 times as there are 8
  characters, inner loop will trigger when it hits the second occurence
  of letter 'a' ("**a***bc***a**bcbb") and will run 2 times for b, c
  (letters in-between), then will trigger for second occurence of
  letter 'b' ("a**b***ca***b**cbb") and will run 2 times for c, a, then
  will trigger for letter 'c' ("ab**c***ab***c**bb") and run 2 times
  for a, b, then again letter 'b' ("abca**b***c***b**b") and run once
  for c. It will then hit the final letter "b" which is again a
  duplicate, but since there are no characters in-between, it will not
  execute any loop.
- I assume the worst case is when I just keep repeating a string. With
  input string "abcdefghabcdefgh" or more readable, "abcdefgh +
  abcdefgh" outer would execute 16 times for every character, inner
  loop would run 8 times when it starts hitting the duplicate letters,
  each time with 7 iterations.
- So if we switch "abcdefgh" to large or infinite nr. of unique characters put together (m), and the full input string is (m + m + m + ...repeated infinitely many times), and the input length is the letter n, then:
- outer loop: runs n times
- inner loop: runs (n - m) * (m-1) // I'm just looking at the previous examples and the relationships there
- n * ((n-m) * (m-1)) // put together
- n * ((n-m) * (m)) // removing -1 constant
- n * (nm - m^2) // simplifying
- So O(n * (nm - m^2))? Or just simple O(n^2)? Or maybe O(n * m)? What is the right answer?

Code:

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(str) {
    // Create storage object for caching
    let storage = {
        longestSubStringLength: 0,
        longestSubString: 0,
        cache: {
            subString: ''
        }
    };
    // Loop through string
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let char = str[i];
        if (!storage.cache[char] && storage.cache[char] !== 0) {
            // If current letter is not in storage, add it and extend current substring
            storage.cache[char] = i;
            storage.cache.subString += char;
        } else {
            // If current letter is already in storage, start a new round
            let previousCache = storage.cache;
            storage.cache = {
                subString: ''
            };
            if (previousCache[char] + 1 !== i) { // If there are letters in-between
                storage.cache.subString = str.substring(previousCache[char] + 1, i);
                for (let j = previousCache[char]; j < i; j++) {
                    storage.cache[str[j]] = j;
                }
            }
            storage.cache[char] = i;
            storage.cache.subString += char;
        }
        // If current substring is the longest, update it in storage
        if (storage.cache.subString.length > storage.longestSubStringLength) {
            storage.longestSubStringLength = storage.cache.subString.length;
            storage.longestSubString = storage.cache.subString;
        }
    }
    return storage.longestSubStringLength;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do jsperf on this Map version

Time complexity of O(n) because a single pass through the string.

Space complexity is O(min(m, n)), where m is the size of the character set, due to  storing the characters and their indices in a map.

It is however a lot more readable

```js
const lengthOfLongestSubstring = str => {
    let cnt = 0;
    let n = str.length;
    let answer = 0;
    let map = new Map(); // to store the strings and their length
    for (let start = 0, end = 0; end < n; end++) { // slide
      // move start if the character is already in the map
      if (map.has(str[end])) start = Math.max(map.get(str[end]), start);
      answer = Math.max(answer, end - start + 1); // longest string
      map.set(str[end], end + 1);
      cnt++
    }
    return [str, `lookups: ${cnt} lookups:`, "answer", answer];
  }
  ["abcabcbb", "bbbbb", "pwwkew", "abcdefghabcdefgh"].forEach(str => console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring(str).join(" ")))
```

Comment: Yeah the code part and the correct implementation of sliding window for this problem are easily understandable for me. I'm having issues only in terms of analyzing the time complexity of my own over-complicated sliding window solution that I posted above. I want to know how to put it into big O notation.

Comment: Aren't actually `map.has` and `Math.max` hiding time complexity by using functions? Don't these functions loop under the hood?

Comment: The Math.max here is not a loop. It is a comparison of two values. The map.has is a lookup - in V8 it is O(1): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation

Comment: @89Tr34Ve Sorry, I did not answer your question then

Comment: @mplungjan my bad, `max` is used on 2 arguments only here, and interesting to know this particularity for `Map` in V8, I thought it would work like `Array.indexOf`

Comment: @Kaddath No it works like `obj[str]`