# Determine how many fields a Javascript object has

Tags: javascript, dictionary, size

I have a Javascript object that I'm trying to use as a "hashmap". The keys are always strings, so I don't think I need anything as sophisticated as what's described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent). (I also don't expect the number of keys to go above about 10 so I'm not particularly concerned with lookups being O(n) vs. O(log n) etc.)

The only functionality I want that built-in Javascript objects don't seem to have, is a quick way to figure out the number of key/value pairs in the object, like what Java's [Map.size](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#size()) returns. Of course, you could just do something like:

```
function getObjectSize(myObject) {
  var count=0
  for (var key in myObject)
    count++
  return count
}
```

but that seems kind of hacky and roundabout. Is there a "right way" to get the number of fields in the object?

Comment: The only suggestion to your method would be to add an additional parameter to exclude/include inherited properties, in that case you would use hasOwnProperty instead of just the simple for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correction: you need to check `myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)` in each iteration, because there're can be inherited attributes. For example, if you do this before loop `Object.prototype.test = 'test'`, `test` will aslo be counted.

And talking about your question: you can just define a helper function, if speed doesn't matter. After all, we define helpers for trim function and other simple things. A lot of javascript is "kind of hacky and roundabout" :)

**update**
Failure example, as requested.

```
Object.prototype.test = 'test';
var x = {};
x['a'] = 1;
x['b'] = 2;
```

The count returned will be 3.

Comment: The object is created with `myObject = {}` and then properties are added to it with `myObject[key] = value` where `key` is always a string. So I think that wouldn't be a concern in this case.

Comment: @MatrixFrog  Oh, really? :)  It doesn't matter what type is 'key'. I added example to clarify the point.

Comment: btw, Anurag presses the same point in his answer (the comment in there)

Comment: I disagree with using hasOwnProperty, only use that if you only want the props on the object itself. In my case, however, I usually want to count inherited properties too. Plus, if you're using an Object as a Map, there are no inherited enumerable properties. Unless you use a naive library that modifies the "prototype" of object, in which case you should know better and have already run into this.

Answer (score 14):

There is an easier way spec'd in ECMAScript 5.

`Object.keys(..)` returns an array of all keys defined on the object. Length can be called on that. Try in Chrome:

```
Object.keys({a: 1, b: 2}).length; // 2
```

Note that all objects are basically key/value pairs in JavaScript, and they are also very extensible. You could extend the `Object.prototype` with a `size` method and get the count  there. However, a much better solution is to create a `HashMap` type interface or use one of the many existing implementations out there, and define `size` on it. Here's one tiny implementation:

```
function HashMap() {}

HashMap.prototype.put = function(key, value) {
    this[key] = value;
};

HashMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
    if(typeof this[key] == 'undefined') {
        throw new ReferenceError("key is undefined");
    }
    return this[key];
};

HashMap.prototype.size = function() {
    var count = 0;

    for(var prop in this) {
        // hasOwnProperty check is important because 
        // we don't want to count properties on the prototype chain
        // such as "get", "put", "size", or others.
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
};
```

Use as ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bs95m/)):

```
var map = new HashMap();
map.put(someKey, someValue);
map.size();
```

Comment: keys only returns the Enumerable, hasOwnProperty keys.

Comment: "TypeError: Object.keys is not a function". I guess I should have mentioned that I'm working on a Firefox extension, so if it doesn't work in Firefox then it's pretty much useless to me. Still, good information for the future. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew - yes, that's why I said *defined on the object* and yes enumerability is important too, but that's what `for..in` will return as well, so I left it out of the discussion. @MatrixFrog - It should be coming in Firefox 4, and you can always defined a custom object type with a size method, as in the above example.

Comment: @Matthew, to get all the properties, enumerable or not, we can now use in ES5 the [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.3.4) method.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just do `myObject.length` (in arrays)

nevermind, see this: [JavaScript object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size/1248343#1248343)

Comment: He's not asking about arrays, or for a `sizeof`.  He wants the number of mappings (key-value pairs) in an object.

Comment: `myObject.length` was my first thought, but yes, it only works for arrays.

Comment: BTW, the link you give is for SIZEOF, e.g. number of bytes used. OP wants to know the number of key-value pairs in an object. (I almost did -1 because this is not an answer to the question; however the link is interesting, even if on a different topic.)

Answer (score 0):

That's all you can do.  Clearly, JavaScript objects are not designed for this.  And this will only give you the number of Enumerable properties.  Try `getObjectSize(Math)`.