# how to query json value for the passed in key

Tags: json

Very simple but didn't have enough time to do a quick search. Kindly help me with the following.

```
public class myKeyValue
{
    public int myKey { get; set; }
    public int myValue { get; set; }
}

IList<myKeyValue> is what gets javascript serialized.

Following is what browser gets in one of its in-memory variable.
[{"myKey":1,"myValue":7},
{"myKey":2,"myValue":286},
{"myKey":3,"myValue":200},
{"myKey":4,"myValue":176}]
```

Now I simply want to access json value for the passed-in key. For example I pass 3 as a key and it returns me 200. I do not want to do it inside loop (that also will work, if there's no other way around). Kindly reply at the earliest.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Javascript :

```
    yourJson = [{"myKey":1,"myValue":7},
                {"myKey":2,"myValue":286},
                {"myKey":3,"myValue":200},
                {"myKey":4,"myValue":176}]

   alert(yourJson[3].myValue); //will output 176
   alert(yourJson["3"].myValue);//will output 176
   alert(yourJson[3].myKey);//will output 4
   alert(yourJson["3"].myKey);//will output 4
```

And if you need hashmap in javascript look at previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent). You best bet may be to loop through and check keyValue. Or if possible just change to zero based on yr original map.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work :( Its is taking "index" as a key. But I want the the value based upon the actual key being passed. Any idea ?