# How to iterate via hashmap items

Tags: javascript, hash

In [Loop through a 'Hashmap' in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748781/looping-through-a-hashmap-in-javascript) I saw recommendation to use 'for' loop to go via elements of hash collection. I implemented that, but the following code:

```
    function MyClass(objs)
    {
        var _objs = objs;

        this.showNames = function () {
            var s = "Names: ";
            for (var obj in _objs) {
                s += obj.getName();
            }
            console.log(s);
        };
    }

    function MyObj(name)
    {
        var _name = name;

        this.getName = function () { return _name; };
    }

    var mc = new MyClass({ 'M': new MyObj("morning"), 'D': new MyObj("Day") });
    mc.showNames();
```

gives error:

> Uncaught TypeError: obj.getName is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Highly recommend that you either get in the habit of including a `hasOwnProperty` check with your for...in loops or using `Object.keys(myObject).map` which does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is the key name and not the value

```
var s = "Names: ";
for (var obj in _objs) {
    s += _objs[obj].getName();
}
console.log(s);
```