# Iteration hashmap object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Any idea how to iterate a hash map object in JavaScript?

I tried the code below but it is not working.

```
for(var key : hmap)
{Alert(key + hmap[keep]);}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through a 'Hashmap' in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748781/looping-through-a-hashmap-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not working because `keep` is not defined?

Comment: *"I tried the code below"* - I guess using syntax from another language was worth a try, but when it didn't work did you not think to read some javascript tutorials/documentation?

Comment: __JavaScript is not Java__. There is no _hashmap_, and if you actually checked your errors you would see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in hmap) {
   alert(key + ':' + hmap[key])
}
```