# How to solve the "TypeError: array.splice is not a function" when 'var array = {}'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove a property from a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)
>   [JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)

I am using jQuery and I am handling a variable this way:

```
var array = {};

array[an_object]      = something
array[another_object] = something_else
array[...]            = ...
```

When I try to run the [`splice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method on the `array` I get a `TypeError: array.splice is not a function`. *My intent is to remove the `an_object` "key" and all its content from the `array` variable.*

How can I make that?

---

*Note*: When I run the `console.log(array[an_object])` (the same is valid for `another_object` and all other objects) I get:

```
[Object { label="str1",  value=1 }, Object { label="str2",  value=2 }, { label="strN",  value=N }]
```

Comment: That's because `array` is not an array.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - I know that is the problem (thus the question title...), but what I have to do to accomplish that I am looking for?

Comment: var array = new Array(); ??

Comment: `var array = {}` is an object `not array`. You can't use array function on the objects.

Comment: http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3099612.htm

Comment: @FelixKling I would go as far as to say that arrays don't have keys in javascript

Comment: @BillyMoon what makes you think so?

Comment: @Billy: Deleted my comment but anyway: Arrays are just objects, so each element of an array is actually a property with a numeric key.

Comment: just because you've named your dog, a donkey id doesn't mean it will not bark, let alone that you can now ride it. That donkey is still a dog. A dog still doesn't have the donkey splices. Instead - you `delete array['unwantedKey']`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, name your variables what they are. The name `array` you're using, is misleading if you use it to create a object.

```
var myObject = {};

myObject[an_object]      = "xyz";
myObject[another_object] = "abc";
```

Now, you can delete the entry in the object with the `delete` statement:

```
delete myObject[an_object]; // Returns true / false if the deletion is a success / failure
console.log(myObject[an_object]) // Returns undefined
```

---

Now, that said, this will not work like you'd expect. `myObject[an_object]` will contain "abc"
Don't use objects as keys. Use strings, instead.
This is because of the fact that any parameter entered in the `[]` will be converted to string. So actually, you're entering `myObject["[object Object]"]`

Answer (score 5):

I am a little confused about the way you are building your object, because `an_object` used as a key would have to be a string value for a key. Assuming you do so, this should work by deleting the undesired property of the object.

```
var array = {};

array['an_object'] = "something"
array['another_object'] = "something_else"

delete(array.an_object)

console.log(array) // Object { another_object = "something_else" }
```

---

**EDIT**

As detailed in comments, if the issue is that objects are being used as keys for another object (in this case confusingly named `array`), then the problem is that an object is first converted to it's string representation to be used in the context of an object key. Therefore, all objects used as keys, will actually refer to one key called `[object Object]`, and whichever object you use as a key will overwrite previous ones.

In the example in the question...

```
array[an_object]      = something
array[another_object] = something_else
// array: Object { "[object Object]" = "something_else" }
```

Comment: there's more to it. He's trying to use an _Object_ as a key.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - It's true.

Comment: @user12882: You cannot use objects as keys. Anything you use as key will be converted to a string. The default string representation for objects is `"[object Object]"`. You could overwrite the `toString` method of each object to return a unique identifier but this solution is not very common (afaik) and might be more confusing than helpful. Better learn first how objects work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't know who down-voted you, I sorry you were down-voted, but it has nothing to do with me I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a Dictionary in simple JavaScript is rather tricky, you would need to create an entire constructor to handle this - or use a library that would handle this for you.

By Dictionary I am refering to an object/hash that can use objects as keys. You would need a constructor that would use multiple arrays (one for the key and one for the value) and that would keep them in-sync. You could mimic many of the typical array methods, but as I stated this would be quite a bit of code.

As a simple alternative you can do the following:

```
function pushToObject(obj, key, value){
  if( !key||!obj ) return false;
  if( !key[''] ) {
    pushToObject.index = pushToObject.index||[];
    key[''] = pushToObject.index.length;
    pushToObject.index.push(key);
  }
  obj[key['']] = value;
  return true;
}

function removeFromObject(obj, key){
  if( !isNaN(key) ) {
    var list = listKeyObjects(obj);
    var item = list[key];
    return removeFromObject(obj,item);
  }
  else if(key) {
    if( !key[''] ){
      return false;
    }
    return delete obj[key['']];
  }
  return false;
}

function listKeyObjects(obj){
  var a = [];
  for(var i in obj){
    a.push(pushToObject.index[i]);
  }
  return a;
}
```

*usage*

```
var array = {}; /// it would be best to change the name of this object
var an_object = {}, another_object = {};

/// add your items to the array object, this handles giving each of your
/// objects used as a key a unique index property. This does mean the objects
/// you use `an_object`, `another_object` are modified.
pushToObject( array, an_object, 'something else' );
pushToObject( array, another_object, 'something other than else' );

console.log(array); /// {0:'something else',1:'something other than else'}

removeFromObject( array, an_object ); /// remove using an object as a key

console.log(array); /// {1:'something other than else'}

removeFromObject( array, 0 ); /// remove using an offset index

console.log(array); /// {}
```

*after thoughts*

Obviously the better option is to create your own dedicated constructor for this, but you could improve the above with a bit more code so that it didn't modify the key objects. Instead whenever working with an object as a key you could scan the `pushToObject.index` for the offset of your key object. I chose to go for the version that modifies your key objects however as it should function faster than having to scan a list every time you make an array modification.

*get key function*

The above code only shows you how to add and how to remove, it may also be a good idea on getting a particular key object from an offset:

```
function getKeyObjectAtIndex = function(obj, index){
  var list = listKeyObjects(obj);
  return list[index] ? list[index] : null;
}

console.log(array); /// {0:'something else',1:'something other than else'}

var key = getKeyObjectAtIndex(array, 1);

console.log(key === another_object) /// === TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynmgj/1/)

```
var array = {};

var an_object = {};

var another_object = {};    

array[an_object] = 'something'

array[another_object] = 'something_else'

alert(array[an_object]);

array[an_object] = null;

alert(array[an_object]);

delete array[an_object]

alert(array[an_object]);
```

Comment: Did you try to run the fiddle? It actually shows that `array[an_object]` is overwritten by `array[another_object]`

Comment: Yes I did run the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fire array method on objects. Your case you have created an object literal instead of an array, define it like `var a = []` OR `var a = new Array();`

Hope it helps !!