# "Multidimensional key" objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

We can write an object in JavaScript as

```
obj1 = {1:2,2:2,3:10}
```

However is there a way to write an object with some sort of "MultiDimensional Key" as

```
obj2= {(1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 1, (1, 4): 1, (1, 5): 1}
```

If not, what could be an easy way of writing such an object???

Comment: Could you make the key "1-1", "1-2", "2-1", etc? That would be a string value but it might work easily enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)

Comment: @drew_w I'd prefer numeric values, although the way you have suggested is quite good.

Comment: This kind of problems are addressed by maps in the world of collections, but since JS is for retarded in this matter - how could you possibly learn about it. Take a look at Java or C# collections libraries and learn them and your life will become a lot more predictable and logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate it like this :

```
obj2 = {
    1: {
        1: 1,
        2: 1,
        3: 1,
        4: 1,
        5: 1
    }
}
```

That's easy to read (for example, to refer to index (1, 3), just do `obj2[1][3]`), but not easy to write (you have to check the existence of the 2nd level key every time).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this, but without objects.

You can use ES6 [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap):

> WeakMaps are key/value maps in which keys are objects.

Or you could also use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> `Map` objects are simple key/value maps. Any value (both objects and
>   primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

Be aware that neither is widely supported, but you can use [ES6 Shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) (requires native ES5 or [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)) to support `Map`, but not `WeakMap` ([see why](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim#weakmap-shim)).

Answer (score 0):

No.

Javascript objects only have string keys.

You could convert your tuples into strings.

Comment: "Javascript objects only have string keys". The `obj1` that I have written works correctly.

Comment: @shauryagupta Because numbers are coerced into strings