# Is there a Map implementation with the same contracts as the ECMAScript 6 Map draft?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I wonder If there is an implementation of `Map` available with the same contract as the [ECMAScript 6 draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), such that could be used as a fallback for Browsers not supporting it? I know there are some implementations, e.g. from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383540/695457) or [from here](https://github.com/flesler/hashmap), but they have different contracts so it would need to be manually adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/), which includes a map, set, and other ES6 features.

Comment: How was I able to live without this :)