# QML wrong integration in javascript hashmaps?

Tags: javascript, qml

I've found an issue tonight and I wonder if this is a mistake between the keyboard and the screen or a QML/javascript integration problem.

Here is my example:

```
var myHash = {}

for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {color: "red"; width: 20; height: 40}', main, "test")
    console.log(newObject.color)
    myHash[newObject] = i
}

for (var key in myHash) {
    console.log("Object type:" + key)
    console.log("Color: " + key.color)
}
```

The output is:

```
qml: Initial color: #ff0000
qml: Initial color: #ff0000
qml: Initial color: #ff0000
qml: Object type:QQuickRectangle(0x98e9ac8)
qml: Color: undefined
qml: Object type:QQuickRectangle(0x98da7a0)
qml: Color: undefined
qml: Object type:QQuickRectangle(0x970b328)
qml: Color: undefined
```

Thus, when I've stored my QML object in the hash-map `myHash` as a key, QML has kept the object type, but forgot the properties?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that JavaScript objects are most closely akin to a `Map[String, Any]` - so you aren't storing the object `newObject` as a key in `myHash` but rather the result of calling `toValue` / `toString` on `newObject`.

The solution is to store `newObject` as a value and use something else for the key:

```
var myHash = {}

for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {color: "red"; width: 20; height: 40}', main, "test")
    console.log(newObject.color)
    myHash["key_" + i] = newObject;
}

for (var key in myHash) {
    console.log("Object entry:" + key)
    console.log("Color: " + myHash[key].color)
}
```

Comment: This is not the good solution because:
- I really want my qml object to be stored into my hash as a key,
- By storing keys in this way, that will be really hard to retrieve my integer from my string key.

Comment: @jaddawyn Why do you want to store it as the key? Your example looks like a flawed design--maybe it is maybe it isn't give us some explaination. Secondly: that's just not how it works, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent

Comment: I don't see any design problem, I just want to associate two QML objects (the code above is just done to highlight my question).
But your link makes me understand javascript is only capable to store strings as a key. I was expecting better.
Anyway thank you for the answers.