# Most efficient way to use an object as a hash key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, caching, memoization

I have a situation in which I would greatly benefit from the use of function caching ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).

However, my function takes a single argument, whose value is a very large and multi-dimensional [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).

The standard way to do caching ( and the only way that I can think of) is to create a `cache` property on the function itself (`cache` is a hash). Each run of the function, you can check for the existence of `myFunc.cache[arg]` and simply return that value if it exists, otherwise you perform the calculations as normal and add the argument as a property of `cache` afterwards.

However, it appears that javascript does not try to evaluate the strings used as hash keys when you are creating them and always just treats them as strings. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r6L7wehn/4/)

I could apply [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to the argument, but because the array will large and nested, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to identify unique arguments.

Comment: Is it some environment you control or just good old browsers? You're basically asking for brand new [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Just a plain old browser

Comment: What would be the desired output of your JSFiddle?

Comment: the desired output is `object` (to indicate that it is an array)

Comment: Why not create your hash like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f1L2pgow/

Comment: @DanielJacobson Because I need a single property on the hash object to represent the arr object in its entirety, so i can do my comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is basically what I was asking without knowing it:

[JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)

In my case, the simplest solution is just to manually make the 0th index of my arrays an ID that I can use as the hash key.

Without a means of doing this, or something similar, you have to either create your own hashmap (outlined in the linked question) or wait for the official [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object to be implemented.