# Angular/Ionic 2 Lodash _.intersection not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I'm doing a simple check that returns no data using _.intersection.  `console.log('intersection', _.intersection(arr1, arr2));`  If I use _.isEqual it correctly returns "false" as there is only one value in arr1 that is in arr2.  Does anyone know why _.isEqual would work and not _.intersection?

Comment: post your array

Comment: `arr1:  
  [{  id: [1234,12345],  
    name: ‘one’,  
  }, {  
      id: [1270,67812],  
    name: ‘two’,  
  }, {  
      id: [4970,5170],  
    name: ’three’,  
  }, {  
      id: [02413,02613],  
    name: ‘four’,  
  }, {  
      id: [8970],  
    name: ‘five’,  
  }, {  
      id: [7170,6570,6370],  
    name: ‘six’,  
  }, {  
      id: [8170,22012,4578,33613],  
    name: ‘seven’,  
  }, {  
      id: [21812,6170,20412,42812,22012,8170],  
    name: ‘eight’,  
  }]`

Comment: `arr2:  
  [{    
    name: ‘one’,  
  }, {  
      
    name: ‘two’,  
  }, {  
}]`

Comment: I'm trying to get the ID's from "arr1" based on names in "arr2" and insert them in another array which includes both names and id's.  For some reason every solution I've come across doesn't work in angular2.

Comment: The last thing I've tried was this:[link](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/23/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-as-a-distinct-list-with-javascript-es6/) it doesn't work as angular doesn't understand the .has method when using .filter.

Comment: Also, tried these approaches: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965688/comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-and-exclude-the-elements-who-match-values-into)

Comment: **UPDATE**  I got this to work doing the following.   `var temp = arr2
var temp1 = arr1
var filterResult = temp1.filter(function(e){
    return  e.name == temp;
});
console.log('filterResult:', filterResult);

this.selected.push(filterResult);`

Comment: **NEW PROBLEM**  --                                     **this.selected.push(filterResult);** 
need to replace the existing "name" with "name" and "id"  i pushed to above array or just add "id" to it.  Currently, this just adds another entry which won’t work correctly ..  It seems there should be an easier way to do this.