# Filter Not Filtering Records

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find records in `$scope.employees`that do not have a matching record in `$scope.allEmployeeGroups`, but the filter is not Filtering records, even though I know for sure that there should only be a few unmatched, it returns all of the records.  For each record, the indexOf == -1 when I know that it should not.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Here is my code:

```
    function getNonGroupEmployees() {
    var arr = $scope.employees.filter(function (item) {
        return $scope.allEmployeeGroups.indexOf(item.EmployeeId) === -1;
    })
    return arr;
}
```

Employee Object:

```
public System.Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SiteId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    public string SsnLastFour { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoginEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLogin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SignatureTypeId { get; set; }
    public string SignatureType { get; set; }
    public string NumberHome { get; set; }
    public string NumberCell { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuperUser { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ModifiedByEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
```

Group Object:

```
            public Guid EmployeeGroupId { get; set; }
        public Guid SiteId { get; set; }
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Guid SiteGroupId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        public Guid? ModifiedByEmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string SiteGroupName { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedByEmployeeName { get; set; }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching object with .IndexOf(), use property matching. Object will not match if two objects do not have same reference.

Try with following code block:

```
function getNonGroupEmployees() {
        var arr = $scope.employees.filter(function (item) {
            return $scope.allEmployeeGroups.find(function(p){ 
                return p.EmployeeId == item.EmployeeId
            })=== null;
        })
        return arr;
}
```

AS requested here are data structures:

Employee:

```
public System.Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> SiteId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
        public string SsnLastFour { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsLoginEnabled { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLogin { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> SignatureTypeId { get; set; }
        public string SignatureType { get; set; }
        public string NumberHome { get; set; }
        public string NumberCell { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuperUser { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ModifiedByEmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }
```

Employee Group

```
            public Guid EmployeeGroupId { get; set; }
        public Guid SiteId { get; set; }
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Guid SiteGroupId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        public Guid? ModifiedByEmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string SiteGroupName { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedByEmployeeName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Unfortunately the above code throws errors.

Comment: Is $scope.allEmployeeGroups list contain same type object as $scope.employees?

Comment: No.  The objects are different.  The only thing they share is the EmployeeId field.

Comment: Can you please share the structure of both objects?

Comment: I have corrected my code block but not sure whether it will solve your problem or not.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort, but new code throws error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965688/comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-and-exclude-the-elements-who-match-values-into), here is what eventually worked:

```
    function getNonGroupEmployees() {
    var result = $scope.employees.filter(function (o1) {
        return !$scope.allEmployeeGroups.some(function (o2) {
            return o1.EmployeeId === o2.EmployeeId;          // assumes unique id
        });
    })
    return result;
}
```