# compare two array of objects with keys and if not found add it to the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
array1 =  [
    {id: 1, height: 178}, {id: 1, height: 176},
    {id: 2, height: 168},{id: 2, height: 164}
]

array2 =  [
    {id: 1, height: ''},{id: 1, height: ''},
    {id: 2, height: ''},{id: 2, height: ''}, 
    {id: 3, height: ''}, {id: 3, height: ''}, 
    {id: 4, height: ''}, {id: 4, height: ''}
]

resultArray  = [
    {id: 1, height: 178},{id: 1, height: 176},
    {id: 2, height: 168},{id: 2, height: 164}, 
    {id: 3, height:''}, {id: 3, height: ''}, 
    {id: 4, height: ''}, {id: 4, height: ''}
]
```

I am looking to compare id of `array1` with id of `array2` and if any objects are missing in `array1` then we add it to that array. Can you suggest me how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to add them incrementally or all at once? I only ask because as soon as you add one, say `id: 3`, then `array1` will have that `id` in it so you wouldn't add more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two arrays of objects, and exclude the elements who match values into new array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32965688/9775003)

Comment: All at once because i am going to map this resultArray to render the table. i am looking to get the result array with all the missing keys in array 2 even if they were duplicated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a set of `array1`'s keys for fast lookup. Note that this mutates `array1`:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 1, height: 178},{id: 1, height: 176},{id: 2, height: 168},{id: 2, height: 164}]
const array2 = [{id: 1, height: ''},{id: 1, height: ''},{id: 2, height: ''},{id: 2, height: ''}, {id: 3, height: ''}, {id: 3, height: ''}, {id: 4, height: ''}, {id: 4, height: ''}]

const ids = new Set(array1.map(e => e.id));

array2.forEach(e => {
  if (!ids.has(e.id)) {
    array1.push(e);
  }
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Nice! I had a feeling there'd be a nicer way to build the `Set` than using `reduce()`

Comment: Great!! This is what I am looking for. Works perfect for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1-Save length of first array

2-Iterate through second array items

3-if the id does not exists or its index is bigger than length of array, push item to first array.

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 1, height: 178 }, { id: 1, height: 176 }, { id: 2, height: 168 }, { id: 2, height: 164 }], array2 = [{ id: 1, height: '' }, { id: 1, height: '' }, { id: 2, height: '' }, { id: 2, height: '' }, { id: 3, height: '' }, { id: 3, height: '' }, { id: 4, height: '' }, { id: 4, height: '' }],
  arr1Length = array1.length;

array2.forEach(function(itm) {
  let index = array1.findIndex(function(it) {
    return it.id == itm.id;
  });
  if (-1 == index || arr1Length <= index) {
    array1.push(itm)
  }
});

console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `id` properties from `array1` using something like `Array.prototype.reduce()` or [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815909/283366)
2. Filter out the entries from `array2` that are not in the `Set`
3. Concatenate `array1` with the filtered result

```js
const array1 =  [{id: 1, height: 178},{id: 1, height: 176},{id: 2, height: 168},{id: 2, height: 164}]
const array2 =  [{id: 1, height: ''},{id: 1, height: ''},{id: 2, height: ''},{id: 2, height: ''}, {id: 3, height: ''}, {id: 3, height: ''}, {id: 4, height: ''}, {id: 4, height: ''}]

// Step #1
const knownIds = array1.reduce((set, {id}) => set.add(id), new Set())

// Steps 2 and 3
const resultArray = array1.concat(array2.filter(({id}) => !knownIds.has(id)))

console.info(resultArray)
```