# Merge items from two arrays based on matching ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, left-join

I have a data object like this :

```
{
  "data1": [
    [
      "ID",
      "name",
      "Birthday"
    ],
    [
      "10",
      "thomas",
      "1992-03-17"
    ],
    [
      "11",
      "Emily",
      "2000-03-03"
    ]
  ],
  "data2": [
    [
      "Balance",
      "ID"
    ],
    [
      "$4500",
      "10"
    ],
    [
      "$1500",
      "13"
    ]
  ]
}
```

It contains two arrays `data1` and `data2`.
The first row in each array is the name of the columns and the rest of the rows have the data (think of it like a table).

I want to compare the `ID` field in both arrays and if the `ID`s match then the final output will contain a column `Balance` with the balance corresponding to that `ID` and if the `ID`s don't match then the `Balance` will be `$0`.

Expected output:

```
{
  "output": [
    [
      "ID",
      "name",
      "Birthday",
      "Balance"
    ],
    [
      "10",
      "thomas",
      "1992-03-17",
      "$4500" //ID 10 matched so the balance added here
    ],
    [
      "11",
      "Emily",
      "2000-03-03",
      "0" //0 bcoz the ID 11 is not there in data2 array
    ]
  ]

}
```

I find this challenging to accomplish. Think of it like a LEFT-JOIN in MySQL.
I referred to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965688/comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-and-exclude-the-elements-who-match-values-into) but it doesn't work in my case as I don't have the keys in my response.

**EDIT**: I also need to join the other fields as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

This solution:

- Handles arbitrary ordering of the items. The order is read from the headers.
- Appends a `Balance` field only if there is one present in `data2`.
- Joins all other fields *(requested by OP, see comments below)*.
- Takes default values as an input and uses them if the data is not present in `data1` and `data2`.

```js
function merge({ data1, data2 }, defaults) {
  // get the final headers, add/move 'Balance' to the end
  const headers = [...data1[0].filter(x => x !== 'Balance')]
    .concat(data2[0].includes('Balance') ? ['Balance'] : []);
  
  // map the data from data1 to an array of objects, each key is the header name, also merge the default values.
  const d1 = data1.slice(1)
    .map(x => x.reduce((acc, y, i) => ({ ...defaults, ...acc, [data1[0][i]]: y }), {}));
  // map the data from data2 to an array of objects, each key is the header name
  const d2 = data2.slice(1)
    .map(x => x.reduce((acc, y, i) => ({ ...acc, [data2[0][i]]: y }), {}));
  
  // combine d1 and d2
  const output = d1.map((x, i) => { // iterate over d1
    // merge values from d2 into this value
    const d = Object.assign(x, d2.find(y => y['ID'] === x['ID']));
    // return an array ordered according to the header
    return headers.map(h => d[h]);
  });
  return { output: [headers, ...output] };
}

const test0 = {
  data1: [[ "ID","name","Birthday","other"],["10","thomas","1992-03-17","empty"],["11","Emily","2000-03-03","empty"]],
  data2: [["other", "ID", "Balance", "city"],["hello", "10", "$4500", "New York"],["world", "10","$8","Brazil"]]
};

const test1 = {
  data1: [["ID","name","Birthday"],["10","thomas","1992-03-17"],["11","Emily","2000-03-03"]],
  data2: [["other","ID"],["x","10"],["y","11"]]
};

console.log(merge(test0, { Balance: '$0' }));
console.log(merge(test1, { Balance: '$0' }));
```

Comment: This solution is not scalable, if you add properties like "Balance", it will not accept them.

Comment: @karkael, I udpated the code to handle arbitrary ordering of the items.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer as it works perfectly for my given scenario. It's neat and I can reuse the function

Comment: will you please add comments in the code around the line   return i === 0 ? [...x, 'Balance'] : [...x, (data.data2.find((y) => y[idIdx2] === x[idIdx1]) || [])[balanceIdx2] || '$0' explaining what the code exactly does as I'm having a little difficulty in undertanding this part : return i === 0 ? [...x, 'Balance']

Comment: thank you so much. but my data won't always have the 'Balance' field. So primarily I need to match values based on the ID field only. If the ID matches then join all the columns. if you can update the answer for this scenario it would be very helpful for me

Comment: @node_man, the solution also works without a `Balance` field in `data2`, I added an example of that case.

Comment: but it still appends 'Balance' and "$0". is it possible that the fields that are not there in the data don't get appended?

Comment: like add an if statement to check if the Balance feild is not present in the data then generate the output without the Balance feild else generate the output with Balance feild?

Comment: Thank you so much @jo_va. You have been really very helpful.

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you suggest me some good reads regarding the concepts you used in this answer. It will help me a lot to accomplish more complex scenarios

Comment: @node_man, I suggest to read about `map` and `find`, I provided the links in the answer, then you can check the spread operator. Of course, you should take the time to read [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS), which is a great and very instructive book on JavaScript.

Comment: consider const test4= { data1: [[ "ID","name","Birthday"],["10","thomas","1992-03-17"],["11","Emily","2000-03-03"]], data2: [["ID", "other","city"],["10", "hello","New York"],["11", "world","Brazil"]] }; //match the ID and then join all the other feilds

Comment: Expected output is { "output": [ [ "ID", "name", "Birthday", "other", "city" ], [ "10", "thomas", "1992-03-17", "hello", "New York" ], [ "11", "Emily", "2000-03-03", "world", "Brazil" ] ] }. how to get output like this? please add it in the answer

Comment: please add this test4 case then this answer will be perfect for all my scenarios

Comment: @node_man, this is a different question, but I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much now I have the perfect answer for all my test cases

Answer (score 1):

```
const KEY_ID = "ID";

var data = {
  "data1": [
    [ "ID", "name", "Birthday" ],
    [ "10", "thomas", "1992-03-17" ],
    [ "11", "Emily", "2000-03-03" ]
  ],
  "data2": [
    [ "Balance", "ID" ],
    [ "$4500", "10" ],
    [ "$1500", "13" ]
  ]
}

var merged = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
  var tmp = data[key].slice();
  var heads = tmp.shift();
  return tmp.map(function (item) {
    var row = {};
    heads.forEach(function (head, i) {
      row[head] = item[i];
    });
    return row;
  });
}).flat().reduce(function (acc, row) {
  var found = acc.find(function (item) {
    return row[KEY_ID] === item[KEY_ID];
  })
  if (!found) {
    found = row;
    acc.push(found);
  } else {
    Object.keys(row).forEach(function (head) {
      found[head] = row[head];
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

This solution is scalable: if you add properties, it will scale the new format.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract all table operations into a class-like:

```
 function Table(array) {
   const [head, ...values] = array;

  const Entry =(entry) => ({
   get(key) { return entry[ head.indexOf(key) ]; },
   set(key, value) { entry[ head.indexOf(key) ] = value; }
  });

  return {
    index(name) {       
      const result = {};
      for(const value of values)
        result[ value[ head.indexOf(name) ] ] = Entry(value);

      return result;
    },
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      for(const row of values)
         yield Entry(row);
     },

      addRow(key) { head.push(key); }
   };
 }
```

Usable as:

```
 const users = Table(obj.data1);
 const balances = Table(obj.data2);

 const balanceByID = balance.index("ID");

 users.addRow("Balance");

 for(const user of users)
   user.set("Balance", balanceByID[ user.get("ID") ].get("Balance"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = { "data1": [ ... ],"data2": [ ...] }
let r = a.data1.reduce((r,u,i)=>{
  if(i !== 0)
  {
    let entry = a.data2.filter((a)=> a[1]===u[0])
    r.push([...u,entry.length ? entry[0][0] : 0])
  }
   return r
},[[
      "ID",
      "name",
      "Birthday",
      "Balance"
]])
```