# Filter for array of objects that contain all key value pairs of one object in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Given I have this array of objects:

```
    let array1 = [
        {id: 1, name: "Test Item 1", price: 100, type: 'item'},
        {id: 1, name: "Test Fee 1", price: 200, type: 'fee'},
        {id: 3, name: "Test 3", price: 300, type: 'item'},
    ]
```

Now i want to filter so I only have the objects where every key value of the following array match:

```
    let array2 = [
        {id: 1, type: "item"},
        {id: 3, type: "item"},
    ]
```

This should return `array1[0]` and `array1[2]`.
My current solution has been this, but it wont work if array2 has multiple object keys to compare to:

```
array1.filter(row => {
    return array2.find(r => {
        return Object.entries(row).some(([key, value]) => r[key] === value);
    })
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two arrays of objects, and exclude the elements who match values into new array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965688/comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-and-exclude-the-elements-who-match-values-into)

Comment: Not really, as that does the inverse and it also filters by a hardcoded key (id), i need to filter by comparing to multiple key/value pairs.

Comment: @GrafiCode array1 should only return objects where each key/value of one of the objects in array2 match. So not only type is taken into consideration, but also id. (note theres two times the same id on array1 with a different type). I'm just bad at explaining :)

Comment: Do it the other way round: `Object.entries(r).every(([key, value]) => row[key] === value)`. Get the entries of `r` and check if `every` value in second array is present in the `row` object

Comment: @adiga You're a hero. Such a simple solution after all. Works flawlessly, thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll be glad to mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
array1.filter((row) =>
  array2.some((template) =>
    Object.keys(template).every((key) => template[key] === row[key])
  )
);
```

I think the answer in comment above is cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 1):

In `array1.filter()` you can iterate all objects in `array2` and compare keys using `Object.keys()`

```js
let array1 = [
  {id: 1, name: "Test Item 1", price: 100, type: 'item'},
  {id: 1, name: "Test Fee 1", price: 200, type: 'fee'},
  {id: 3, name: "Test 3", price: 300, type: 'item'},
]

 let array2 = [
   {id: 1, type: "item"},
   {id: 3, type: "item"},
 ]

const res = array1.filter(row => {
  for (const obj of array2) {
    if (Object.keys(obj).every(k => obj[k] === row[k])) {
      return row
    }
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Lodash** if you don't mind:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 1, name: "Test Item 1", price: 100, type: 'item'},{id: 1, name: "Test Fee 1", price: 200, type: 'fee'},{id: 3, name: "Test 3", price: 300, type: 'item'}];
const array2 = [{id: 1, type: "item"},{id: 3, type: "item"}];

const fn = _.overSome(array2.map(_.matches));
const result = _.filter(array1, fn);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```