# Add item to array or substitute it if it has the same id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects

```
var source = [
  {id: 1, label: "one"},
  {id: 2, label: "two"},
  {id: 3, label: "three"}
];
```

I need to add an item or substitute it if it has the same id

```
var new_sub = {id: 1, label: "new label for one"};
var new_add = {id: 4, label: "four"};

source = myFunc(new_sub);
source = myFunc(new_add);

function myFunc(obj) {
  return (source.findIndex(x => x.id === obj.id) === -1) ? 
  source.concat(obj) : source.map((item) => {
    return (item.id === obj.id) ? obj : item;
  });
}
```

This code works perfectly, but is there a better way to do this?
You can check my code to this snippit:

```js
var source = [
      {id: 1, label: "one"},
      {id: 2, label: "two"},
      {id: 3, label: "three"}
    ];
var new_sub = {id: 1, label: "new label for one"};
var new_add = {id: 4, label: "four"};

source = myFunc(new_sub);
source = myFunc(new_add);

function myFunc(obj) {
  return (source.findIndex(x => x.id === obj.id) === -1) ? 
   source.concat(obj) : source.map((item) => {
     return (item.id === obj.id) ? obj : item;
    });
}

//PRINT
var html = "";
source.map((item) => {
 html += "<li>" + item.id + " - " + item.label + "</li>";
});
$("#resp").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="resp">
</ul>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent as i see it something[obj.id] should work fine?

Comment: @Camile it should be `[obj.id - 1]` and it is not a solid way of doing this.

Comment: Do you need to create a new array each time you call the function?

Comment: Just a note: `=>` functions are not supported by `IE`

Comment: Better in what way? Are you looking for better performance (I guess not since you don't state array size or your performance shortfalls and requirements)? Or better more readable code?

Comment: more readable code and  better performance

Comment: Code optimised for performance is rarely more readable. Normally you don't optimise for performance and sacrifice readability before you have identified this piece of code as a performance bottleneck in your system. Have you?

Comment: in this case, I need more readable

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc(obj) {
  let i = source.findIndex(x => x.id === obj.id); // get the index
  if(i === -1) sources.push(obj);                 // if there isn't any object that have the same id, then push this obj into the array
  else sources[i] = obj;                          // if there is then replace it
  return sources;                                 // this won't be necessary the array get mutated so no need to store it back into sources (see note bellow)
}
```

**Note:** Your version of `myFunc` creates a new array each time it is called. My version doesn't. But since you are storing the return value of `myFunc` back into `sources`, I guess creating a new array isn't needed (in my version you won't have to do `sources = myFunc(...)` as the array `sources` get mutated).

**Older browsers support: (and actually better)**

```js
function myFunc(obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sources.length && sources[i].id !== obj.id; i++) // stop when reaching the end of the array or when we find an object with the same id
    ;                                                                  // empty loop (just using it to find the index)
  sources[i] = obj;                                                    // i will be either the index of the found object (so it will be replaced by obj) or sources.length (so obj will be added to the array)
}
```

Comment: You're *modifying* the input array. The OP's code makes a new array. That's an important semantic difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right. But I've just noticed that he is doing `sources = myFunc(...)`, thus creating a new array is not necessary. I added a note too.

Comment: @Red That OP's choice. He already was using arrow functions and `findIndex`.

Comment: Yeah, i know. Just noticing it for users who want to use this function for other cases :)

Comment: @Red actually the older browser version look way better than the other version :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I agree

Answer (score 1):

You're making multiple passes over the array (one in `findIndex`, then one in either `concat` or `map`), which is unnecessary. Just a single pass will do it:

```
function myFunc(a, obj) {
  let found = false;
  const result = a.map(e => {
    if (!found && e.id === obj.id) {
      found = true;
      return obj;
    } else {
      return e;
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note that I passed the source array into the function as an argument, so it doesn't have side-effects.

```js
var source = [
  {id: 1, label: "one"},
  {id: 2, label: "two"},
  {id: 3, label: "three"}
];

var new_sub = {id: 1, label: "new label for one"};
var new_add = {id: 4, label: "four"};

source = myFunc(source, new_sub);
source = myFunc(source, new_add);

console.log(source);

function myFunc(a, obj) {
  let found = false;
  const result = a.map(e => {
    if (!found && e.id === obj.id) {
      found = true;
      return obj;
    } else {
      return e;
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Of course, if the array is small and you know that's the standard case, it doesn't really matter.

If you want to be concise at the expense of (in my view) abusing the `,` operator:

```
function myFunc(a, obj) {
  let found = false;
  const result = a.map(e => e.id === obj.id ? (found = true, obj) : e);
  if (!found) {
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this often (insert a few thousand elements) it may be better (concerning performance) to build up a hash table ( which has a lookup time of O(1) instead of O(n) for searching an array):

```
var source = [
  {id: 1, label: "one"},
  {id: 2, label: "two"},
  {id: 3, label: "three"}
];
var hash = new Map(source.map((el,i)=>[el.id,i]));

function substitute(elem){
  var i = hash.get(elem.id);
  if(i !== undefined){
    return source[i] = elem;
  }
  hash.set(elem.id,source.push(elem));
}
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/jakunacava/edit?console)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
    function myFunc( o )
    {
      let i ;
      if ( (i = source[0].indexOf(o.id)) < 0 )
      {
        source[0].push(o.id) ; source.push(o)
      }
      else
      {
        source[1 + i] = o
      }
      // return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source)) // new Array with primitives
      return source  // As reference
    }
    
    var source = [
        [4, 1, 3, 2] // the trick here
      , {id: 4, label: "four"}
      , {id: 1, label: "one"}
      , {id: 3, label: "three"}
      , {id: 2, label: "two"}
    ];
    
    var new_sub = {id: 1, label: "new label for one"};
    var new_add = {id: 6, label: "six new label"};
    
    source = myFunc(new_sub);
    
    console.log("// => source after new sub", source);
    
    source = myFunc(new_add);
    
    console.log("// => source after new add", source);
```