# How to compare each object in an array with each other. When found update the object with a new property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js, lodash

For example consider the following array with objects.

```
var collection = [{name:'user1',phone:'203'},
                  {name:'user2',phone:'5050'},
                  {name:'user1',phone:'203'}]
```

Now I want to compare the each object with each other and give the result as.

```
var newCollection =   {name:'user1',phone:'203', rowMatch:'true'},
                      {name:'user2',phone:'5050', rowMatch:'false'},
                      {name:'user1',phone:'203',rowMatch:'true'}
```

So, I want the new collecition like this where it compares and updates with new property when object properties match like the first and third object.

Comment: you mean if 2 or more rows are same, you need to set the `rowMatch` to true ?

Comment: Even if one row matches with another you have to update both the object with rowMatch : true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use newCollection or manipulate in the collection like this

```
collection.forEach((item)=>{
item.rowMatch = (collection.filter((e)=>{return (e.name==item.name&&e.phone==item.phone)}).length>1)?'true':'false';
})
console.log(collection)
```

Simple is that.Here is working JSFiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/touqeer/pgdsw9Le/1/ .

Comment: @Rick Jolly No this will not.You can see working fiddle in edited answer now.Thanks

Comment: Find will not let you know the length.The basic logic is to find more iteration of an object.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the `length > 1`. Deleted my comments to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks man.If you have tried this then upvote.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah it works but would rather see `item.rowMatch = (condition)` or `item.rowMatch = (condition) ? 'true' : 'false'` if strings are necessary. I also don't prefer the filter inefficiency and direct mutation though.

Comment: this is less performant for an already poor performance operation, filter demands that you continue checking even after a match is found rather than stopping when 2 are found. Find should be used instead.

Comment: Answer updated as you want but i think filter have to be there as we would have to iterate on all items for taking length of matched items

Comment: this method works, but it is worse performance than using find.  The big O with this method is always n^2, with a find operation instead, the big O is significantly lower.

Comment: Find gets the value of the first element in the array that has a matched value.

Comment: Thanks @Ajay you are awesome.If this was helpful than please accept the answer and give it an upvote.Thanks again man.

Comment: yes, which is why you just need to add a simple check to make sure you're not looking at the same object. Then it stops iterating after it finds a match that isn't the current object.  Much better performance. Your method does needless iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newCollection = collection.map(item => {
   item.rowMatch = !!collection.find(i => i !== item && i.phone === item.phone && i.name === item.name);
   return item;
});
```

Here you're just using map to iterate through and check if each item has a duplicate that isn't the original.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash function for your object type.

A simple concatenation of the fields seems to work in this case. Iterate through your collection and for each element, hash it, and put it in a table.

Keep track of the counts. When the count is greater than 1 you know you have a duplicate (row match)

[JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)

Comment: then he'll need to go back through to assign the property to the previous item

Comment: A simple concat could produce false positives.

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.prototype.find`

```
var newCollection = collection.map((row, index) => {
       if(row["rowMatch"])
          return row; 

      rowMatch = !!collection.find((r,i) => i !== index && r.name === row.name && r.phone === row.phone); 
      row["rowMatch"] = rowMatch;

      return row; 

})
```

Comment: this will always find the item you're currently on, need to exclude it. and your find usage is off, find doesn't return -1 if not found, it returns undefined.

Comment: @bryan60, yup saw that now, returns `undefined`, using double not now.