# Does javascript object handles hash collision under the hood?

Tags: javascript, hash

For now,I currently use the plain object as a substitute for hash table for key-value. My question is that does javascript handle collision under the hood?

There seemed to be conflicting information in popular post about this topic such as [JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)

Comment: run JSON.parse('{"a":1,"a":2}') in console and see the result.